# Is there a way to determine the optimal value for the bs parameter to dd?

Tags: performance, dd, file-copy

On occasion I've seen comments online along the lines of "make sure you set 'bs=' because the default value will take too long," and my own extremely-unscientific experiences of, "well that seemed to take longer than that other time last week" seem to bear that out.  So whenever I use 'dd' (typically in the 1-2GB range) I make sure to specify the bytes parameter.  About half the time I use the value specified in whatever online guide I'm copying from; the rest of the time I'll pick some number that makes sense from the 'fdisk -l' listing for what I assume is the slower media (e.g. the SD card I'm writing to).

For a given situation (media type, bus sizes, or whatever else matters), is there a way to determine a "best" value?  Is it easy to determine?  If not, is there an easy way to get 90-95% of the way there?  Or is "just pick something bigger than 512" even the correct answer?

I've thought of trying the experiment myself, but (in addition to being a lot of work) I'm not sure what factors impact the answer, so I don't know how to design a good experiment.

Comment: writing to the same storage medium is different than writing to a different storage medium and would require different optimal settings, there are many variables which will be different for everyone, depending on device type, speed, cache and so on. On my machine bs=256M is optimal.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/147935/how-to-determine-the-best-byte-size-for-the-dd-command || http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd || http://superuser.com/questions/234199/good-block-size-for-disk-cloning-with-diskdump-dd

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`dd` dates from back when it was needed to translate old IBM mainframe tapes, and the block size had to match the one used to write the tape or data blocks would be skipped or truncated.  (9-track tapes were finicky.  Be glad they're long dead.)  These days, the block size should be a multiple of the device sector size (usually 4KB, but on very recent disks may be much larger and on very small thumb drives may be smaller, but 4KB is a reasonable middle ground regardless) and the larger the better for performance.  I often use 1MB block sizes with hard drives.  (We have a lot more memory to throw around these days too.)

Comment: Hard drives or USB mass storage devices are either 512 or 4096 (newer) bytes.  Optical and direct access flash media is 2048 bytes.  Can't go wrong with 4096 bytes.

Comment: Why the copying program's block size should have anything to do with the underlying device's characteristics (tapes excepted)? The kernel does its own buffering (and sometimes prefetching) anyway.

Comment: To minimize fractional buffers; things in general go faster when you use aligned buffers because the kernel can start buffer reads/writes at sector (or better, track or cylinder, but I think modern drives lie about those) and kernel buffer boundaries, because the kernel isn't having to skip over stuff or read extra stuff or manage partial buffers.  Certainly you can just let the kernel deal with it all, but if you're copying gigabytes of data that extra work can cut the copy time down considerably.

Comment: You (generally) need to include `@Gilles` if you want me to be notified of your comment reply, see [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). Since I happened to be passing by: the kernel will deal with it all anyway. Your claim that “that extra work can cut the copy time down considerably” doesn't agree with my benchmarks, but different systems may have different behaviors, so please contribute timings too!

Comment: @Gilles: sorry, I had mistaken you for the original asker.

Answer (score 83):

There's but one way to determine the optimal block size, and that's a benchmark. I've just made a quick benchmark. The test machine is a PC running Debian GNU/Linux, with kernel 2.6.32 and coreutils 8.5. Both filesystems involved are ext3 on LVM volumes on a hard disk partition. The source file is 2GB (2040000kB to be precise). Caching and buffering are enabled. Before each run, I emptied the cache with `sync; echo 1 >|/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`. The run times do not include a final `sync` to flush the buffers; the final `sync` takes on the order of 1 second.

The `same` runs were copies on the same filesystem; the `diff` runs were copies to a filesystem on a different hard disk. For consistency, the times reported are the wall clock times obtained with the `time` utility, in seconds. I only ran each command once, so I don't know how much variance there is in the timing.

```
             same   diff
             t (s)  t (s)
dd bs=64M    71.1   51.3
dd bs=1M     73.9   41.8
dd bs=4k     79.6   48.5
dd bs=512    85.3   48.9
cat          76.2   41.7
cp           77.8   45.3
```

**Conclusion:** A large block size (several megabytes) helps, but not dramatically (a lot less than I expected for same-drive copies). And `cat` and `cp` don't perform so badly. With these numbers, I don't find `dd` worth bothering with. Go with `cat`!

Comment: I'd recommend the OP to do his own benchmarking, but anyway, nice answer!

Comment: not in the context of the topic, @Gilles, what is the difference in `echo 1 >|/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` and `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Comment: @Nikhil `>|` is the same as `>` except that under `set -o noclobber`, the shell will complain that the file exists if you use `>`.

Comment: @Gilles Would you `cat` whole HDD of 500GB too in cloning? Any better way?

Comment: @Masi Yes, if I want to clone a whole disk, I'll use `cat`. Why are you looking for a better way? What's wrong with `cat`?

Comment: @Gilles I am just a newbie who have HDDs which have some broken sectors so worried about copying with them. So what you propose is `cat /media/HDD1 > /media/HDD2`. Is there any limitation about Size? HDD1 is always smaller/equal than HDD2, which I think must be maintained.

Comment: @Masi `cat` just copies its input to its output. If you want to copy from unreliable media, and skip over unreadable parts or retry multiple times, that's a different problem, for which [`ddrescue`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) works pretty nicely.

Comment: Well, `dd` reports the amount of data copied and the speed both during and after the copy, while `cat` does not, so it's a lot nicer when you're trying to clone a disk.

Comment: @sudo You can get the amount of data copied with `lsof`. Instant speed isn't very relevant with a disk copy because it's uniform so you can divide bytes transferred by elapsed time; if you want something better, you can use `pv`.

Comment: @Gilles In my experience, `pv` significantly bottlenecks the copy, so I only use it for slower things like network transfers. And how is `cat` better than `dd` at this point if it's not any faster, and you have to go manually calculate the throughput?

Comment: @sudo `cat` is faster if you don't get the `bs` parameter right, and unlike using `dd` with the `bs` parameter, there's no risk that it'll skip data in the middle,

Comment: @Gilles Ah, so if you don't know what `bs` to use, I now see that `cat` picks automatically based on the system buffer and filesystem block sizes. I still see `dd` perform much better in certain cases if you're careful, but I can see why you'd use `cat`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' If you remember, can you please explain what do (did, could) you mean by "risk of skipping data in the middle" using dd?

Comment: PS. I've looked in the internet for dd being risky in this context, but with no luck.

Comment: @Silv https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32988/why-does-dd-from-dev-random-give-different-file-sizes

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thank you! I didn't expect you to remember what you were about 3 years ago. :) That's a useful reading (along with a couple of other SO questions I encountered reading it).

Comment: Which commands were used exactly for dd, cp and cat?

Comment: @Cadoiz The commands shown, plus the filename arguments or redirections. In cases where both a file name and redirection could be used (e.g. `cat` input), I don't remember which one was used, but it doesn't make any difference anyway (they don't use different `open` flags or anything that could affect the speed of the copy).

Comment: The more times I return to this answer the more I question *why* `cat` or `cp` would be faster than`dd`; what's going on in userland or kernalland to make this happen.  Is `dd` using a different syscall to write the data?  If not then is there any possibility the benchmark is being unfair?  Could `dd` be executing an `fsync()` that's not performed by `cat`?

Comment: @PhilipCouling I think it's due to the size and sequencing of read and write calls. `dd` forces a read of `bs` bytes followed by a write of `bs` bytes. Other tools can pick more optimal sequences if they want. But I don't know what `cat` and `cp` actually do.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Also, `cp` and `cat` in modern Busybox (≥1.23, 2014 release) uses the `sendfile` system call, and the latest coreutils (≥9.0, Sep 2021 release) uses `copy_file_range` on Linux. Both give the kernel considerable opportunity to pick optimal buffer sizes and to interleave device reads and writes in an optimal way.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' the different syscall makes more sense to me than discussion of tuning read/write sizes especially with sizes >= 1mb.  I can imagine that boxing up the data to pass to userland and visa-versa comes with overheads (extra copying?).  In any case, thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with [geekosaur's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9433/318461) that the size should be a multiple of the block size, which is often 4K.

If you want to find the block size `stat -c "%o" filename` is probably the easiest option.

But say you do `dd bs=4K`, that means it does `read(4096); write(4096); read(4096); write(4096)`...

Each system call involves a context switch, which involves some overhead, and depending on the I/O scheduler, reads with interspersed writes could cause the disk to do lots of seeks.  (Probably not a major issue with the Linux scheduler, but nonetheless something to think about.)

So if you do `bs=8K`, you allow the disk to read two blocks at a time, which are probably close together on the disk, before seeking somewhere else to do the write (or to service I/O for another process).

By that logic, `bs=16K` is even better, etc.

So what I'd like to know is if there is an upper limit where performance starts to get worse, or if it's only bounded by memory.

Comment: Profile, don't speculate!

Comment: Absolutely.  I am doing that now.  But your benchmarks already illustrate the point.

Comment: [The Linux Programming Interface](http://nostarch.com/tlpi) agrees with me.  See Chapter 13 - File I/O Buffering.

Comment: Interestingly, their benchmarks suggest there is little benefit above 4K however.

Comment: Also, apparently the default file read ahead window is 128 KB, so that value might be beneficial.

Comment: If you want your data to be hard to recover after you delete it on a hard drive you should use a larger blocksize as smaller block sizes (1m for example) make a hard drive fairly easy to recover

Comment: I have access to a 24 drive RAID50 here, where bs=8K gets me 197MB/s but bs=1M gets me 2.2 **GB/s** which is close to the theoretical throughput of the RAID. So bs matters ALOT. However using bs=10M I only get 1.7GB/s. So it appears to get worse over some threshold, but not sure why.

Comment: @JosephGarvin Yes, I always find it worthwhile to play around a bit with the block size if I'm doing a large transfer. It seems the optimum block size depends on a lot of different things.

Comment: I want to mention that the improvements with larger `bs` stagnate. Consider this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144177/318461

Comment: This article is also interesting: http://blog.tdg5.com/tuning-dd-block-size/

Answer (score 4):

As [Gilles says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9492/318461), you can determine the optimal parameter for the **bs** option to **dd** by benchmarking. This, though, begs the question: how can you conveniently benchmark this parameter?

My tentative answer to this question is: use [dd-opt](https://github.com/sampablokuper/dd-opt), the utility I've recently started working on to solve precisely this problem :)

Comment: What is the sensitivity of the output? 90-95% or >95%? I do not find that you can change it.

Comment: @Masi, I'm afraid I haven't worked on `dd-opt` in a long time. However, it is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Free_software&oldid=695656324#Definition_and_the_Four_Freedoms) licensed under the [AGPLv3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affero_General_Public_License). So, feel free to improve it and to evalutate its sensitivity/accuracy!

Answer (score 3):

> If not, is there an easy way to get 90-95% of the way there?

Use `bs=1M`

It'll give you more than 95% optimal performance over more than 85% your devices, from slow USB2/3 flash drives, SD cards and hard-drives to NVMe SSDs and even RAM-only devices such as `/dev/zero`.

Source?

Voices in my head.

And some empirical testing over 10+ years combined with pseudo-scientific benchmarking and biased common sense.

Hey, you asked about the *easy* way!

Answer (score 0):

I optimized for sdcard reader usb2.0 which seems to run best at `bs=10M`. I
tried 4k, on up to 16M,  after 8-10M no improvement.  You can see how the transfer rate measurement degrades...most likely due to loading up the buffers on the device then waiting for the device to transfer to the actual medium.

```
angstrom/sdcard# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=10M
123+0 records in
123+0 records out
1289748480 bytes (1.3 GB) copied, 21.4684 s, 60.1 MB/s
341+0 records in
341+0 records out
3575644160 bytes (3.6 GB) copied, 117.636 s, 30.4 MB/s
816+0 records in
816+0 records out
8556380160 bytes (8.6 GB) copied, 326.588 s, 26.2 MB/s
955+0 records in
955+0 records out
10013900800 bytes (10 GB) copied, 387.456 s, 25.8 MB/s
```

Comment: The option `status=progress` can be used for monitoring. You could also consider this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144178/318461