# Why does dd from /dev/random give different file sizes?

Tags: linux, dd, random

I am running the following command on an ubuntu system:

```
dd if=/dev/random of=rand bs=1K count=2
```

However, every time I run it, I end up with a file of a different size.  Why is this?  How can I generate a file of a given size filled with random data?

Comment: `/dev/random` will block if there is not enough entropy available to generate the number of digits you want. it simply takes time to gather that amount of high quality psuedo random "randomness"... Either use `/dev/urandom` for a less random "random" value, or check your entropy pool (in a loop, and wait as need be)...

Comment: See also [this question](http://superuser.com/q/359599/92954).

Comment: just add `iflag=fullblock`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You're observing a combination of the peculiar behavior of `dd` with the peculiar behavior of Linux's `/dev/random`. Both, by the way, are rarely the right tool for the job.

Linux's `/dev/random` returns data sparingly. It is based on the assumption that the entropy in the pseudorandom number generator is extinguished at a very fast rate. Since gathering new entropy is slow, `/dev/random` typically relinquishes only a few bytes at a time.

`dd` is an old, cranky program initially intended to operate on tape devices. When you tell it to read one block of 1kB, it attempts to read one block. If the read returns less than 1024 bytes, tough, that's all you get. So `dd if=/dev/random bs=1K count=2` makes two `read(2)` calls. Since it's reading from `/dev/random`, the two `read` calls typically return only a few bytes, in varying number depending on the available entropy. See also [When is dd suitable for copying data? (or, when are read() and write() partial)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial)

Unless you're designing an OS installer or cloner, you should never use `/dev/random` under Linux, always `/dev/urandom`. The `urandom` man page is somewhat misleading; `/dev/urandom` is in fact suitable for cryptography, even to generate long-lived keys. The only restriction with `/dev/urandom` is that it must be supplied with sufficient entropy; Linux distributions normally save the entropy between reboots, so the only time you might not have enough entropy is on a fresh installation. Entropy does not wear off in practical terms. For more information, read [Is a rand from /dev/urandom secure for a login key?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key) and [Feeding /dev/random entropy pool?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89/feeding-dev-random-entropy-pool/7074#7074).

Most uses of `dd` are better expressed with tools such as `head` or `tail`. If you want 2kB of random bytes, run

```
head -c 2k </dev/urandom >rand
```

With older Linux kernels, you could get away with

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=rand bs=1k count=2
```

because `/dev/urandom` happily returned as many bytes as requested. But this is no longer true since kernel 3.16, [it's now limited to 32MB](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=775328).

In general, when you need to use `dd` to extract a fixed number of bytes and its input is not coming from a regular file or block device, you need to read byte by byte: `dd bs=1 count=2048`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using head instead of dd.  That allows me to still use /dev/random if I want to.  Although /dev/urandom would probably be sufficient as you mention, it is nice to know how to use /dev/random should the need arise.

Comment: on kernels since 3.16 `/dev/urandom` [returns 32m per `read()`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=775328).

Comment: Alternatively, if you need a POSIX compliant command, you can use the trick here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192114 `dd if=/dev/urandom ibs=1k obs=1k | dd bs=1k count=2`

Answer (score 11):

From `man 4 random` on a RHEL 5 box:

> When read, the /dev/random device will only return random bytes 
>   within the estimated number of bits of noise in the entropy pool.

I get files of size 213 bytes on that machine.  Back to man 4 random:

> When  read,  /dev/urandom  device  will  return  as  many  bytes as
>   are requested.

I get 2048 bytes from every invocation of `dd if=/dev/urandom of=rand bs=1K count=2`

I conclude that the difference is due to how much entropy your machine generates between invocations of `dd if=/dev/random ...`

Comment: Yeah, practically, unless he's at a real crypto application, @Daniel should use /dev/urandom.  But I'm puzzled as to why `dd if=/dev/random bs=1K count=2` stops when the entropy pool is apparently drained. From the docs, it should block until there's more entropy, so the `dd` will write out the file slowly, instead of just dumping out the current pool and exiting.

Comment: I wondered about that too, but it's consistent across RHEL, Slackware 13.1 and a pretty current Arch.  The RHEL was x86_64, the others were 32-bit.  Unfortunately the dd docs are in GNU info format, so I haven't read them all.

Comment: It's also consistent on Gentoo too.

Comment: @cjc: It's because when you call `read(fd, mybuf, 1024)` on a blocking FD it returns as soon as the underlying device returns *some* data. If there are 1024 bytes there to be read, it returns that. If there are only 201 bytes, it will return 201. If there are 0 bytes available, it will block until at least one byte becomes available, then return it/them.

Comment: @WarrenYoung does reading from /dev/random drain its contents? I assume so.

Answer (score 4):

Why does `dd` drop data? ... *Gilles* has posed this engaging question about `dd`:
[When is dd suitable for copying data? (or, when are read() and write() partial)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial)
Here is an excerpt from that question:

*...it's not difficult to put dd at fault; for example try this code:**
        `yes | dd of=out bs=1024k count=10`
    *and check the size of the out file (it's likely to be well under 10MB).*

---

Aside from my comment (at the end of your question), something like this is iteresting to watch... It catches your bytes in file `$trnd`. I've semi-arbitrarily chosen bs=8

Move your mouse and watch it speed up.
With my computer idle (AFK and no Network activity), and after exhausting the entropy pool, it took *2 **hours** 12 minutes* to collect only **1192** bytes, at which point I cancelled it.

Then, with me moving the mouse continuously, it took a relatively much shorter *1 **minute** 15 seconds* to collect the same number of bytes.

This shows pretty clearly that collecting entropy is not CPU speed based, but rather it is **random events** based, and that my Ubuntu system uses the mouse as one of its *significant* random factors.

```
get=2048
trnd=/tmp/$USER.rnd; >"$trnd"
while (( $(wc -c <"$trnd") < $get )) ;do
    dd if=/dev/random bs=8 count=1 2>/dev/null >>"$trnd"
    echo -n "itt: $((i+=1))  ct: "; wc -c <"$trnd"
done
truncate -s $get "$trnd"
echo -e "\nfinal count: "; wc -c <"$trnd"
```

Answer (score 1):

`dd` is *designed* for blocking - it is usually the best tool at your disposal for reading from variable sized inputs if you need it done *immediately* because `dd` will not buffer current reads into some future `write()` *(unless you very explicitly configure it that way with larger obs than ibs)*, but will instead `write()` everything it reads as soon as it `read()`s it *(and optionally processes it)*.

Here are some important [definitions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/utilities/dd.html):

- `ibs=`*`expr`*

  - Specify the input block size, in bytes, by *`expr`* *(default is 512)*.
- `obs=`*`expr`*

  - Specify the output block size, in bytes, by *`expr`* *(default is 512)*.
- `bs=`*`expr`*

  - Set both input and output block sizes to *`expr`* bytes, superseding `ibs=` and `obs=`. If no conversion other than `sync`, `noerror`, and `notrunc` is specified, each input block shall be copied to the output as a single block without aggregating short blocks.

So you see, when `ibs` and `obs` are defined together as `bs` then `ibs` takes precedence - but otherwise, if you are specific, then either `obs` or `cbs` does.

Here is an example in which `ibs` is most important. You might do something like this if you wanted to track how soon the `/dev/random` pool filled...

```
dd "ibs=$size" conv=sync "count=$lmt" \ 
    if=/dev/random of="$somefile"
```

As long as `if=`'s target is readable at all, that will *always* result in the same sized output file, because `dd` will `sync`hronize blocks read-in on nulls. In other words, if `dd` `read()`s for an input-block of `$((size=10))` `$((count=5))` times and the `read()` file returns 2 bytes, then 8 bytes, then 12 bytes, then 2 bytes, then 4 bytes, `dd` will write to its outfile something like

```
 2 read bytes 8NULs \
 8 read bytes 2NULs \
10 read bytes 0NULs \
 4 read bytes 6NULs \
 4 read bytes 6NULs
```

...because `dd`, by default, does *not* delay. So if you need to track in-stream and delimit the writes of some other process, `dd` is the tool for you.

If you're just writing some amount of data to a regular file then, contrary to other statements made here, you can also use `dd` for this - and fairly easily - but you'll need more than one and a reliable blocking *factor*.

For example, if you did:

```
{   dd ibs="$size" obs="${size}x$block_factor" |
    dd bs="${size}x$blockfactor" "count=$lmt"
}  <infile >outfile
```

...the first `dd` would buffer as many `ibs="$size"` input blocks as were necessary to fill at least one `obs="${size}x$block_factor"` output block for every `write()` to the pipe between it and the second `dd`. This means that the second `dd` can limit the output reliably with `count="$lmt"` because all of the `write()`s the first makes will match its i/o blocksize - *regardless* of how many `read()`s the first `dd` must do to make it so.

And *that*'s how you can use `dd` to reliably read pipes or other types of special files - with just a little bit of math.