# Dirty in /proc/meminfo for dd

Tags: memory, io, proc

I read from [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/9105/find-out-how-much-data-is-waiting-to-be-written-to-disk) that the below command gives me the amount of data that needs to be written to the disk.

```
grep ^Dirty /proc/meminfo
```

It particularly says *Ever ask yourself "How much data would be lost if I pressed the reset button?"*

I wanted to test the above command and so I did the following.

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=sample.txt bs=1G count=1
```

Now, in another shell I ran the above command.

```
grep ^Dirty /proc/meminfo
Dirty:                44 kB
grep ^Dirty /proc/meminfo
Dirty:                36 kB
```

However, if I do a file copy using `cp` it reports,

```
grep Dirty /proc/meminfo
Dirty:            387680 kB
grep Dirty /proc/meminfo
Dirty:            609172 kB
```

I see from [this](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-meminfo.html) page what Dirty does.

> Dirty — The total amount of memory, in kilobytes, waiting to be
>   written back to the disk.

Why **Dirty** is not reporting any size in case of `dd`?

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, you answered your title in your question.

Comment: @Braiam, Thanks. changed the title to be more meaningful.

Comment: @Ramesh: You should use `watch -n 1 grep Dirty /proc/meminfo` to see the updated result till `dd` finished.

Comment: You may be surprised because you believe that `dd` is reading the amount of data you think you told it to read — but that isn't actually the case: the `bs` parameter is only accurate in rare circumstances. Read [Why does dd from /dev/random give different file sizes?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32988/why-does-dd-from-dev-random-give-different-file-sizes/33009#33009) and use `cat` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this command instead:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=sample.txt bs=1M count=1024
```

`dd` will only write assign the data to be written to disk when it got all of the `bs` size in its memory.

Here is the output of `ps` for a `dd` of 128mb just before the output was written to disk:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND    
root      4465  100 12.8 236260 129784 pts/1   R+   17:15   0:13 dd if=/dev/urandom of=sample.txt bs=128M count=1
```

You can see the process is using about 130mb of ram (RSS Column)