# Got "No space left on device" when cloning 1TB disk to 1.2TB disk using dd

Tags: linux, filesystems, command, dd

I am trying to using the following `dd` command to clone remote xfs disk to another location.

```
ssh root@source_ip  "dd if=/dev/vda2 bs=16M conv=noerror,sync status=progress " | sudo dd of=/dev/nvme1n1 bs=16M conv=noerror,sync status=progress
```

However, I got the following error msg

```
828895133696 bytes (829 GB) copied, 39610.432258 s, 20.9 MB/s
1288490188800 bytes (1.3 TB) copied, 64529.849170 s, 20.0 MB/s
dd: error writing '/dev/nvme1n1': No space left on device
```

The source disk has 1TB and the target disk has 1.2TB.

Can anyone help to explain why can't perform the disk to disk clone in this situation? Thanks!

I want to try to recover the deleted files from the source disk, and I'm not sure whether DD is the only right tool for this situation.

Comment: Please remove `conv=sync` from the right-hand dd and try the command line again. If that still gives you errors, please add `iflag=fullblock` to the right-hand dd.

Comment: The different byte counts on first and second line (which come from the first and second `dd`, respectively) are a strong clue that, as Mark says, you need `iflag=fullblock`.

Comment: `dd: bad argument: "iflag=fullblock"` so this is not related to `dd`. I added an answer that is based on a standard `dd` implementation.

Comment: `dd` is not a tool for cloning and will clone every single sector into the new disk even if it's unused. Use a proper cloning tool instead. They're smarter and much faster

Comment: You're using Linux here based on your tags, I very strongly recommend that when cloning disks over the network, you don't use a network pipe, but use a rpoer network block storage protocol to expose the target disk on the source system or vice versa. NBD is what I tend to prefer for this, but ATAoE and iSCSI work too. This will let you use a proper cloning tool like `ddrescue` and turn most network reliability issues into performance issues instead of letting them corrupt data.

Comment: use **xfsdump** and **xfsrestore** since you are dealing with an **XFS** file system.  Many online articles telling on how to do specifically what you are trying to do.

Comment: Don't copy raw disk data from one disk to another (except if they are 100% identical and you know what you are doing).  Instead copy files with tar or cpio.

Comment: As a general rule, using `conv=` options with `dd` is a mistake.

Comment: Incidentally, your title says you're cloning a disk. Your command shows you cloning a partition of a disk. Are you sure the target is (at least) the same size as the source?

Comment: yeah you got fscked by the lack of `iflag=fullblock` - you need it on both dd's

Comment: ```I want to try to recover the deleted files from the source disk, and I'm not sure whether DD is the only right tool for this situation.``` - no it's not. use ddrescue for that. https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Invoking-ddrescue

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for posting this question.  I learned something about dd today, and a little about cloning disks too.  Cheers!

Answer (score 31):

Compare [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33009/108618) (note `bs=1K` is used there):

> `dd` is an old, cranky program initially intended to operate on tape devices. When you tell it to read one block of 1kB, it attempts to read one block. If the read returns less than 1024 bytes, tough, that's all you get.

`conv=sync` gets important when `dd` indeed reads less than it expected. In your case any time the pipe from `ssh` fails to deliver a full `16M` block (because of `bs=16M`) to the local `dd` *in one read*, the `conv=sync` of the latter will fill the "missing" data with zeros (NUL bytes). But the real data is not missing. What the local `dd` considers missing will be delivered when it tries to read the next block.

In effect the local `dd` injects zeros in random(-ish) places of the stream. In case it's not obvious I emphasize: **this corrupts the data, the resulting "clone" will be virtually useless**.

Using `conv=noerror,sync` even on the remote (reading) side may be wrong. Compare this answer: [What does `dd conv=sync,noerror` do?](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/432690) You need to really know how it works to use it properly.

For the local `dd` `conv=noerror,sync` you used makes little sense. Drop it or add `iflag=fullblock` (if supported). Frankly I'm not sure if `conv=noerror,sync iflag=fullblock` has any advantage over not using these options at all in a case when `dd` reads from a pipe.

Comment: Better still, don't use `dd` at all

Comment: @roaima: what should be used, then?

Comment: @a3nm `cat` should do, or `pv` for a nice progressbar. `pv /dev/sda > /dev/sdb`

Comment: Yes, in this example OK. But for more complicated use cases, `dd` has options (seek, skip, etc.) that you can't replicate with just `cat`

Comment: @a3nm in those situations consider using `dd`. But generally for straightforward replication of disks or disk partitions, `dd` is most definitely not the way to go. (And that's what this question is about.)

Comment: I want to try to recover the deleted files from the source disk, and I'm not sure whether DD is the only right tool for this situation.

Comment: @Tim it isn't by any means.

Comment: @Tim for forensics, DD the origial disk to a file on the new disk.  You can still use that file as a disk image.

Comment: Whatever happened to --retry-partial? It basically fixed `dd` to do almost nothing stupid as it would use part reads to fixup part reads until the whole block was read or EOF was reached.

Answer (score 23):

As others have already identified, the problem is that you're using `dd`. Rule #1 of using `dd` is you do not use `dd`. Rule #2 of using `dd` is you do *not* use `dd`. Rule #3 of using `dd` (for experts only) is don't use the `bs` option.

There is no magic in `dd`. The magic is in `/dev/*`.

[`dd` will happily mangle your data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32988/why-does-dd-from-dev-random-give-different-file-sizes/33009#33009) and [setting a block size may or may not help performance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492). Only use `dd` if you've figured out how to use it safely *and* you've done benchmarks in your specific use case to determine block sizes that are faster that letting the system do its thing.

```
ssh root@source_ip  "cat /dev/vda2" | sudo tee /dev/nvme1n1 >/dev/null
```

Comment: Probably worth `ssh root@source_ip "gzip </dev/vda2" | zcat | sudo tee /dev/nvme1n1 >/dev/null` for all those potentially empty blocks

Comment: @roaima Yes, good point. Or simpler: `ssh -C`.

Comment: What advantage does `tee` provide here?

Comment: @Binarus `sudo tee myfile` is one way to write `myfile` as root. `sudo sh -c 'cat >myfile'` is another. `sudo cat >myfile` wouldn't work since the surrounding shell would open `myfile`, and it's not running as root: only `cat` runs as root, but `cat` doesn't open its output, it just writes to its standard output.

Comment: Thank you very much, and +1. I have got your point. I didn't come to that idea because I'm mostly working as `root` in such cases (not normally).

Comment: If somebody else comes here: With a Hitachi 80 GB SATA (Deskstar 7K250) disk from 2007 as destination, and with debian bullseye from 2023, I just ran into that "no space left" error regardless of what cloning method I used. That happened even without SSH being involved. I wanted to overwrite the disk and as root did `cat /dev/random > /dev/sdc`. That indeed overwrote the disk, but at the end lead to the "no space left" error; the same with `dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/sdc ...`. With other disks, both methods work without that error. Maybe some disks simply report the wrong size to the O/S.

Answer (score 8):

For anything involving forensics, including undeleting files, `dd` is the RIGHT tool (at least for the read).

The problem, as others have pointed out, is that at the end of a ssh pipe, you aren't reading it blocked.  So you either need iflag=fullblock on the second dd, or to just skip the second dd altogether.

`flag=noerror` is probably wrong.  You want to know if it failed.

`flag=sync` is often a mistake.  It tells dd to override the OS's buffering.  You don't need that.  At most, run `sync` afterwards.  And for reading, it is meaningless.

Two different `status=progress` entries is a mistake.  Both will report overwriting each other.  You really just want to know how it finished.  Omit status=...

`bs=16M` seems nice, but ideally bs should match the hardware block size.  For classic disks, that was 512 bytes.  More modern ones use 4k.  I would recommend 4k, 16k, or 64k.

For disks that aren't full, compression is also good.  The `ssh -C` solution is probably easiest.

So you could write:

```
ssh -C root@source_ip  "dd if=/dev/vda2 bs=64k" | sudo dd iflag=fullblock of=/dev/nvme1n1 bs=64k
```

or

```
sudo sh -c 'ssh -C root@source_ip  "dd if=/dev/vda2 bs=64k" >/dev/nvme1n1'
```

(this one might have ssh issues)
or

```
sudo chown `id -u` /dev/nvme1n1
ssh -C root@source_ip  "dd if=/dev/vda2 bs=64k" >/dev/nvme1n1
sudo chown root /dev/nvme1n1
```

or use the rather clever solution involving using `tee`.

### testing

If you want to use the double dd form, it is probably good to test that you've got the right options before doing the full transfer.  Add `count=100` to the first `dd` so that it does a little bit of the disk.  You should see both status lines in a few seconds and they should show the same amount transferred.  If it works, repeat with the `count=100` removed to do the full disk.

Answer (score 3):

The command `dd` was modeled after the command `DDR` (Disk Dump and Restore) from IBM mainframes from the 1960s and is mainly intended to convert and reblock block oriented I/O from/to block oriented disks. This is however not what you intend to do here.

The important problem in your use case is than you have an unreliable network pipe in the middle that does not grant to read specific block sizes.

If you are using a real `dd` program (not sure what you use since your output is  incompatible to the standard) you should get output like this:

```
"%u+%u records in\n", <number of whole input blocks>,
    <number of partial input blocks>

"%u+%u records out\n", <number of whole output blocks>,
    <number of partial output blocks>
```

You need to use `dd` in a way that makes sure that you only get numbers > 0 before the plus sign and a 0 after the plus sign.

Since there is no grant to get a specific amount of data when reading from the `ssh` output pipe, you need to make sure to always try to read less than you would get. You could still use the following command to read from the source disk:

```
dd if=/dev/xxx bs=16x1024k
```

without problems, but you need to use this command to read from the pipe and to write to the destination disk:

```
dd ibs=1b obs=16x1024k of=/dev/yyy
```

Do not user other options (in special none of the non-standard option you are using). If the `dd` command that writes to the destination disk finally writes:

```
nnnn+0 records in
mmmm+0 records out
```

you have been successful and `dd` did never read less than 512 bytes from the input and thus could correctly reblock the output.

If you see partial blocks (> 0 to the right of the plus sign) for the input blocks, you need to repeat the copy process.

Note that because of the large output blocksize, you of course may get one partial block written to the destination dist at the end. So the summary message for the `dd` that writes to the destination disk may alternatively be:

```
nnnn+0 records in
mmmm+1 records out
```

Comment: If you have a block size that doesnt cleanly divide to the data size you can get a +1 at the end due to the last block being incomplete.

Comment: OK, but only for the output blocks. I'll correct that.

Comment: I suspect dd is based on the DD statement in IBM mainframe's JES2 or JCL environment (early to mid 1960s).  That actually specified the mapping between an internal filename and an external filename, and could also do certain actions on the file, like deleting it, or releasing a tape.  It was not unusual for the work of a job to be in the DD statements, and the program to be IEFBR14 (a standard return immediately program).  The DD statement's syntax tended to be:  //<internal_name> DD <keyword>=<value>,...