# gzip - redirection or piping?

Tags: linux, gzip, pipe, dd

I will be backing up a large (750GB) disk to an external USB disk using dd.
Should I be using redirection or piping? Which is more efficient? Or is there a difference?

Also, what is the best block size? USB is likely to be the bottleneck here.

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M | gzip -c > /mnt/sdb1/backups/disk.img.gz

gzip -dc /mnt/sdb1/backups/disk.img.gz | dd of=/dev/sda bs=1M
```

vs

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M | gzip -c | dd of=/mnt/sdb1/backups/disk.img.gz

dd if=/mnt/sdb1/backups/disk.img.gz | gzip -dc | dd of=/dev/sda bs=1M
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would try to backup file systems, not raw disk images. And to tune the parameters, you'll have to benchmark.

Comment: `dd` is archaic (any other tool thankfully does away with `bs=` and `count=`, like `ddrescue`), and in your case also pretty much pointless. Just pipe it into `gzip -c </dev/sda >disk.img.gz` & `gzip -cd disk.img.gz >/dev/sda`.

Comment: Or do it with rsync. Just construct the command with the parameters, and it will do you everything in the most efficient way it thinks.

Comment: In the second command of the second listing, what is the `dd if=.../disk.img.gz |` part supposed to do? As far as I understand, `gzip -dc` (=`zcat`) doesn't care for its `stdin` when there's a file argument.

Comment: I don't think Linux can reliably reproduce Windows installations by simply copying the file structure. Hence, the need for bit-wise copying like `dd`. `ddrescue` looks more robust then plain `dd`. Would you use GNU `ddrescue` or `dd_rescue`? What is a good Live CD to download?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to use `dd` or piping at all.

```
</dev/sda gzip >/mnt/sdb1/backups/disk.img.gz
</mnt/sdb1/backups/disk.img.gz gunzip >/dev/sda
```

I once [made a benchmark](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492) and found using `dd` slower than `cat` for a straight copy between different disks. I would expect the pipe to make any solution involving `dd` even slower in this case.

Comment: That *is* an example of using redirection.

Comment: @psusi Gah! I meant to write “dd or piping”. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to combine `pv` in these commands?

Comment: @Yaron Sure: replace `gzip` by `pv | gzip` and `gzip -d` by `gzip -d | gv`

Comment: So, just to be sure, using redirection on an unmounted device, like `</dev/sda` or `</dev/sda1` will read raw disk data, and not the file system, is it correct? I need this to work with a Windows partition.

Comment: @mcu Right: `/dev/sda` is the whole disk, and `/dev/sda1` is one whole partition. This just reads the data on the disk/partition without caring if that data may have some meaning as a filesystem.

Comment: Would this terminate the copying process somewhat gracefully if the user presses `Ctrl+C`?

Comment: @mcu It'll interrupt the copy in progress, leaving a partial image file if interrupted during the first command and a half-written (unmountable) disk if interrupted during the second command. A truly graceful interruption that restores the destination disk to its original content if interrupted is not really doable.

Comment: How might we adjust the command containing the pipe to add sudo so that it can run as superuser (needed to access the raw disk)? `</dev/nvme2n1 pv | gzip >disk.img`

Comment: Update: Seems like `sudo bash -c "</dev/nvme2n1 pv | gzip >disk.img"` is working for me

Answer (score 3):

Piping involves one more process and one more user-land copy, so it *should* be more efficient to use redirection.

But I guess that on nowadays hardware & software caching system, it should not make any real difference. Maybe you can have better results using `bs=4k` or `bs=64k`, since it's the [pipe's limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624071/pipe-buffer-size-is-4k-or-64k) under linux. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/234199/good-block-size-for-disk-cloning-with-diskdump-dd) for more detail about different *bs* parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler:

```
gzip -c /dev/sda > disk.img.gz
gzip -dc /mnt/sdb1/backups/disk.img.gz > /dev/sda
```