# Is there a difference between these two commands?

Tags: bash, command-line, posix

```
cat a > b
```

and

```
cp a b
```

If they are functionally the same for all intents and purposes, which one is faster?

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Answer (score 6):

In terms of functionality I think they are the same.

If I had to venture a guess about which is faster, I would say the [cp](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cp) command because its purpose is to do file operations just for copy purposes, so it would be optimized for that.

[cat](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cat), by contrast, is meant *concatenate* files, meaning joining several files into a series. If no file is specified, it will display a file to the console (thanks to @bahamat for reminding us). In this example the output is redirected to another file. I think this indirection would be less efficient than a direct `cp`.

I don't know if the difference would be noticeable for regular sized files, though it would be interesting to time these on very large files. I guess one could do repeated trials with /usr/bin/time and see if one is consistently faster/slower than the other.

Do you have any particular reason to ask about this, or is it just simple curiosity (nothing wrong with that at all of course)

Comment: I'm also wondering if there are some strange cases where `cat` might modify the contents as it passes it through whereas `cp` wouldn't. I don't know enough about the details of what goes on here. What drove me to ask the question is I saw in one of my shell scripts two tasks accomplishing the same thing but using these different methods and I started wondering what the difference was between them, and if I had that in mind when I wrote them.

Comment: There is 1 important functional difference between the 2; permissions. `cp` will try and keep the same file permissions (mode) on the new file as are on the original. Obviously this may not be possible due to filesystem restrictions or other factors though.

Comment: Good point about `cat` .. since it's main purpose is to display data, perhaps it would tweak the data for display purposes ever so slightly? I guess I would use `cp` for copy, not `cat`

Comment: Won't cat stop at an EOF character?

Comment: `cat` is *not* to display a file to the screen. `cat` is short for "concatenate", which is defined as "to unite in a series or chain". The original purpose of `cat` was to combine multiple files into one (e.g., `cat file1 file2`). It just so happens that if you combine one file with nothing it prints only that one.

Comment: @Patrick `cp` will keep the same permissions only if `-p` option is used. Otherwise it will create absolutely new file according to `umask`. Issue about timestamps is the same.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod there is no such thing a an EOF that `cat` responds to when reading from a file. @Steven `cat` is designed to be perfectly transparent. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Exactly. End of file is signalled out-of-band (comparing the file position against the file size). The C EOF return value is -1 and is only a special return flag for some C functions, not a value encountered in a file.

Comment: @bahamat I knew that `cat` stood for concatenate (its right there on the man page), though I don't think I new about its original purpose to join multiple files into one - thanks for the information.

Comment: @bahamat I updated my answer with your information, thanks for helping to improve the information presented.

Comment: @bahamat Actually, the [Word of God](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordOfGod) is that it's both: [“cat file is about the easiest way to print a file. Also: cat filel file2 >file3 is about the easiest way to concatenate files.”](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/cat).

Comment: @rush from the man page: `preserve the specified attributes (default:  mode,ownership,timestamps)`. Note the default part. And I've even tested it, it preserves the mode without passing the argument, and no, I dont have an alias set.

Comment: @Gilles: Yeah, in 1971, more than 2 years after UNIX was created (though, not necessarily cat). The 1st edition manual merely documented what was already in use, not the original intention of the authors (which is probably lost).

Comment: @bahamat The 1st edition man page is the intention of the authors, the manual was written by dmr and kt. Admittedly it may not be their *original* intention, but rather what they concluded after some initial use.

Comment: @Gilles: exactly my point, it is "what they concluded after some initial use". Sometimes the secondary use of something is far more beneficial than the *original* intention. Unix itself was written to play Star Trek. I'm glad they found it had other uses too :-)

Answer (score 4):

Functionally similar, but specifically different. Essentially, they both read a bunch of data from the first file, write it to another file.

When I do an *strace* on Linux:

```
$ strace cat /etc/fstab > test.txt
...
open("/etc/fstab", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=691, ...}) = 0
fadvise64_64(3, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL) = 0
read(3, "# /etc/fstab: static file system"..., 32768) = 691
write(1, "# /etc/fstab: static file system"..., 691) = 691
read(3, "", 32768)                      = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?

$ strace cp /etc/fstab test.log
...
open("/etc/fstab", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=691, ...}) = 0
open("test.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_LARGEFILE, 0644) = 4
fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# /etc/fstab: static file system"..., 32768) = 691
write(4, "# /etc/fstab: static file system"..., 691) = 691
read(3, "", 32768)                      = 0
close(4)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
_llseek(0, 0, 0xbfaa3fb0, SEEK_CUR)     = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Comment: Did you forget the `-f` in your strace of the cat-command, or where is the open for FD 1?

Comment: @Nils there is no open for FD 1, its already open when the program is executed (programs inherit open file descriptors, and FD 1 is already opened by the shell).

Answer (score 3):

There isn't much difference: both copy the content of the old file into a new file with the same content. Both overwrite the target if it is an existing file.

Some old systems might stop copying or truncate lines if you try to copy binary files with `cat`, because they might choke on null characters. I don't think any unix system you're likely to encounter now has a problem there. `cp` is guaranteed not to have a problem.

`cp` allows you to specify a directory as the destination: the file is copied to have the same name as the original, in the new directory.

If the destination doesn't exist, `cp` uses the permission bits of the source file, modified by the current [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask).

You can protect against overwriting the target file when doing `cat … >target` by setting the `noclobber` option in the shell with [`set -C`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html). You can protect against overwriting the target file with `cp` by passing the `-i` option (`alias cp='cp -i'`); `cp` will ask for confirmation.

It is often useful to preserve the date of the original file. You can use `cp -p` for that.

Performance will vary, depending on the size of the file, the filesystem, the kind of source and target disk, the operating system, etc. [For raw disk copies under Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492), I found next to no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Look like cat is `faster` than cp

```
root@SHW:/tmp# time cp debug.log test1
real    0m0.021s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
root@SHW:/tmp# time cat debug.log > test2
real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
root@SHW:/tmp# du -h debug.log 
4.0K    debug.log
root@SHW:/tmp# file debug.log
debug.log: ASCII text
```

Comment: Does the `time` also include the `>` operation, of only the cat command itself?

Comment: Yes. It includes `>` operation. Time takes `command` as an argument

Comment: Your measurement proves nothing. The time is far too small to be measured accurately.

Comment: Yeah. But you can crosscheck against GB files.

Comment: Please repeat your test with a different file using `cat` first. Then cat is probably slower than `cp`. I suspect you are seeing a file being read from cache in the second command.