# Does dd do any kind of verification?

Tags: dd, verification, integrity

I'm using `dd` to copy data from an old hard drive to a new one. I want to be sure that the data's integrity is secure.

On this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45854/188870), Gilles says

> If [dd] terminated successfully, then the backup is correct, barring a hardware fault…

What does that mean exactly? Does `dd` have some kind of built in verification?

If I were to use rsync instead, I run a second pass with `--checksum` as well, to verify. Is that kind of paranoia justified?

Comment: Define "integrity is secure".

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I mean that the copy is identical to the original.

Comment: If you only have flat files, the traditional way for copying files is using tar or cpio.  GNU tar has a verify flag:  https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_81.html.   These days `rsync` would probably be the simplest.

Comment: "barring a hardware fault" indicates that it *doesn't* do any verification. If it did, it could detect the hardware failure.

Answer (score 22):

`dd` or any other application does not have “some kind of built in verification” in the sense you're probably thinking of: it doesn't read back the data from the storage medium to compare with what was written. That's the job of the operating system.

It is not really possible to do a read-verify down to the hardware from an application. It would work in some scenarios, but in most cases it would achieve nothing. The application could read back what it just wrote *if it's writing directly to a storage medium*, but that would typically read back from an in-memory cache, which wouldn't give any useful assurance. In [the example you cite](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45817), `dd` is writing to a pipe, and in that case it has no control over what happens to the data further down the line. In your rsync example, a second pass of `rsync --checksum` is pointless: in theory it could catch an error, but in practice, if an error does happen, then the second pass would probably not report anything wrong, so you're wasting effort on something that doesn't actually give a useful assurance.

However, applications *do* verify what happens to the data, in the sense that they verify that the operating system has accepted responsibility for the data. All system calls return an error status. If a system call returns an error status, the application should propagate that error to the user, generally by displaying an error message and returning a nonzero exit status.

Beware that `dd` is an exception: depending on the command line parameters, **[`dd` might ignore some errors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial)**. This is extremely unusual: `dd` is the only common command with this property. Use `cat` instead of `dd`, that way you don't risk corruption and [it may well be faster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492).

In a chain of data copying, two kinds of errors can arise.

- Corruption: a bit is flipped during the transfer. There is no way to verify this at the application level, because if that happens, it's due to a programming bug or hardware error that is highly likely to cause the same corruption when reading back. The only useful way to verify that no such corruption happened is to physically disconnect the media and try again, preferably on a different computer in case the problem was with the RAM.
- Truncation: all the data that was copied was copied correctly, but some of the data was not copied at all. This one *is* worth checking sometimes, depending on the complexity of the command. You don't need to read the data to do that: just check the size.

Comment: I believe most storage mediums use enough FEC to detect + correct a single bit flip.

Comment: Of course if you copy an entire hard disk with dd and then immediately compare the hard disk you know it worked because the cache isn't big enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1). I probably should mention I'm using a fairly basic `dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdb bs=4M`, so my understanding is that the issues of ignoring errors and speed (more or less, compared to `cat`) are moot. Are you saying to just check the size by mounting then `df`?

Answer (score 8):

No, `dd` does not do an explicit verification.   If you want/need a forensically verified copy of your disk or any part of it, use `dcfldd` which is an enhanced version of `dd` developed by the U.S. Department of Defense Computer Forensics Lab.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to this.

Comment: That's interesting. But sadly it doesn't have flag to verify data after write.

You need to generate checksums during copy, and then generate chacksums on second  pass.

Comment: Update. This utility should not be used anymore, at state of 2023. It's not suitable fror SSDs and NVMe's specifically. Max speed I had with it was 190 MiB/s after tuning bs, and even lower before palying with buffer size. But with dd and buffer of 32M I was able to acheive 2GiB/sec. So basically `dd` + `sha256sum` twice gave me far faster result.   Can also use https://github.com/Xfennec/progress to track progress of `sha256sum`

Answer (score 6):

The only way to be "sure" is to do an additional read-and-compare pass (after dropping caches).

Aside from that, `dd` detects read and write errors the same way all other programs do... it works if the drives (and other components involved) report errors; for drives that accept data silently w/o actually writing them you're out of luck.

> Is that kind of paranoia justified?

If you can't trust your hardware to be reliable, things get complicated...

Comment: [It's more complicated than this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366251), both about read-and-compare and about `dd` detecting errors.

Comment: Well, if you're going that far, `dd` has [serious data corruption issues](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/195171) but special cases such as these were not part of the question.

Comment: Those corruption issues could justify verifying the data produced using `dd`. The real solution is to use anything but `dd` since silent data corruption is a specialty of `dd`.

Comment: @Gilles, or just don't tell `dd` to ignore errors.  You can't exactly blame a program for doing exactly what you asked it to.

Comment: @Mark And how, pray, to you tell `dd` not to ignore errors? And no, `conv=noerror` is not a correct answer. See [frostschutz's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1075837) for an example. I *do* blame the design of `dd` for making ignoring errors a default mode, and one that cannot be turned off without knowing its internal mechanics very precisely.

Comment: @Gilles in the simple case of `dd bs=1M if=/dev/a of=/dev/b` which errors does it ignore? The links all go to very broad/special use cases so it's unclear what exactly you're on about

Comment: @frostschutz I'm not sure about this one, which is why I avoid it and recommend against it (it's just a slow, complicated way of writing `cat` anyway). [When I asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial), nobody came up with an informed answer — I only got answers that assured that it was safe, with handwaving arguments that also claimed some other, proven unsafe, uses were safe.

Comment: Proving Non-Existence [of corruption issues in `dd` or anywhere] is hard (and some would say, the wrong thing to ask for); usually if you claim that `dd` is unsafe, you're supposed to provide evidence. I agree `dd` has a plethora of confusing options, but that's not what the question was about. The question was "I want to be sure that the data's integrity is secure. Does `dd` have some kind of built in verification?" - in that regard it's the same difference if you use `cat`, `cp`, `ddrescue`, ... - they all don't, it's just read and write but not verify for all of them.

Comment: Verification in general is a new fad (such as checksumming in ZFS, btrfs) usually we just rely on both software and hardware to not mess things up for us (and whatever error checking capabilities they have built in) and it works surprisingly well most of the time.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, faulty hardware may insert random error bits in the data at some rate as one bit per number of megabytes, this is possible and takes place in practice sometimes.

Usually, I use md5 or sha1 hash to verify the data is intact, by re-reading both the source and the destination, e.g.:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=~/hd_backup
dd if=/dev/sdb | md5sum
dd if=~/hd_backup | md5sum
```

This assumes that the data is much larger than the filesystem cache, otherwise, you may need to re-start the system to verify the actual data on the medium and not the cache contents, or use another system for it.

Comment: It is sufficient to unmount/mount the filesystem to force the OS to write the filesystem cache to the device.

Comment: miracle173, but even after syncing, doesn't the OS keep in cache what it wrote ? so i'm not sure unmounting will clear all cache from RAM.

Answer (score 1):

From `man dd`:

> When finished, dd displays the number of complete and partial input and output blocks, truncated input records and odd-length byte-swapping blocks to the standard error output.
>
> A partial input block is one where less than the input block size was read.  A partial output block is one where less than the output block size was written.  Partial output blocks to tape devices are considered fatal errors.  Otherwise, the rest of the block will be written.  Partial output blocks to character devices will produce a warning message.

`dd` verifies the input/ouput block sizes match every time it copies a block. If they don't, it handles the error with a warning or fatal error (overidden with `noerror`). That's why `dd` works virtually all the time.

Still, it doesn't replace manually verifiying the integrity of your disk. If the information is valuable to you, then yes, **your paranoia is justified**. Run a manual verification  once `dd` is finished.

Comment: `dd` does not work virtually all the time: [with the `bs` parameter, it ignores some errors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial).