# Cubian: NAND and Partitions

Tags: cubian, cubieboard

I have installed Cubian on Cubieboard using SD. After that I moved it to NAND. NAND have 4 Gb memory and I want to leave there only boot, another partitions move to the SD. Maybe leave on NAND something else? But I fear overflow memory when will install more programs.

Can I moved partitions and if true how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with partitions there are 2 ways to move their content. You can either make an exact copy of the partition(s) using a tool such as `dd` or copy the contents of the partition(s).

#### exact copies

This approach will not only copy the content but also the filesystem's metadata too. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish this may be a good or bad thing.

**NOTE:** You're literally making a byte for byte copy of the drive.

For example, say you have 2 harddrives, 1TB & 2TB. Let's imagine that all your data is currently on the 1TB and you'd like to move/migrate it to the 2TB drive. If you were to enlist the help of `dd`, you'd only be able to clone the drive as is onto the 2TB drive, there by wasting the balance of the larger space.

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

#### copying data

The other approach is to createcompletely discrete drives/partitions from one another. Then copy the contents of the partition on the 1TB drive (/dev/sda1) to a partition on the 2TB drive (/dev/sdb1), using a tool such as `rsync`.

Once you have the partitions squared away you'll need ot mount them:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/ssd
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/backup-drive/ssd-backup
```

And then use `rsync` to copy:

```
$ sudo rsync -ax /media/ssd /media/backup-drive/ssd-backup
```

Comment: Why insist on using `dd`? `cat` is [faster](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492) and less error-prone (`i` and `o` are so close on most keyboards).