# What is the easiest way to clone an embedded Linux SD card?

Tags: linux

I have a 8 GB SD card (card 1) installed with embedded Linux for [PowerPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC), libraries and some applications. I want to prepare another 8 GB SD card (card 2) exactly like card 1. What is the easiest way to do this?

I tried copying all the files from card 1 to a Linux laptop and then from the laptop to card 2, but I am getting some *permission denied* errors in spite to doing this as root. Is my approach correct? Please suggest any other techniques.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about `dd`? You can use it to do a 1:1 copy of your SD card to a new one:

```
dd if=/dev/<your_old_sd_card> of=/dev/<your_new_sd_card>
```

Or to copy it to a file:

```
dd if=/dev/<your_sd_card> of=/a_file.img
```

Comment: I have a single SD card slot. What should I use to transfer the img to the sd card 2?

Comment: Use a greater block size (e.g. `bs=1M`) to speed up the transfer. You can use `dd if=/dev/<your_sd_card> of=/path/to/file` to copy the sd card to an imagefile and then after plugging in your new SD card: `dd if=/path/to/file of=/dev/<your_sd_card>` to copy the image to the SD card

Comment: The 1M blocksize should be enough, as long as you don't use the default blocksize (when not specifying the bs option). Anything bigger than 1M does not make a significant difference. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd

Comment: @Vinz How can you estimate how much still command will take time on your SD card? I want to evaluate how much it would take with 500GB discs, ..., 5 TB discs in cloning.