# Create random data with dd and get "partial read warning". Is the data after the warning now really random?

Tags: dd, random

I create a 1TB file with random data with `dd if=/dev/urandom of=file bs=1M count=1000000`. Now I check with `kill -SIGUSR1 <PID>` the progress and get the following:

```
691581+0 Datensätze ein
691580+0 Datensätze aus
725174190080 Bytes (725 GB) kopiert, 86256,9 s, 8,4 MB/s
800950+1 Datensätze ein
800950+0 Datensätze aus
839856947200 Bytes (840 GB) kopiert, 99429,5 s, 8,4 MB/s
dd: warning: partial read (809620 bytes); suggest iflag=fullblock
803432+1 Datensätze ein
803431+1 Datensätze aus
842459273876 Bytes (842 GB) kopiert, 99791,3 s, 8,4 MB/s
```

I can't interpret the warning. What does it say? Is my file really random after the warning or is there a problem?
What does +0 or +1 in `800950+1 Datensätze ein` and `800950+0 Datensätze aus` mean? After the warning it is +1. Is it a errorcount?

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you could translate the messages into English. Also, define "really random". What level of randomness do you require, what will you use it for?

Comment: To get English messages, use `LC_ALL=C` in front of the command, like `LC_ALL=C dd if=...`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Summary: `dd` is a cranky tool which is hard to use correctly. Don't use it, despite the numerous tutorials that tell you so. `dd` has a “unix street cred” vibe attached to it — but if you truly understand what you're doing, you'll know that you shouldn't be touching it with a 10-foot pole.

`dd` makes a single call to the `read` system call per block (defined by the value of `bs`). There is no guarantee that the `read` system call returns as much data as the specified buffer size. This tends to work for regular files and block devices, but not for pipes and some character devices. See [When is dd suitable for copying data? (or, when are read() and write() partial)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial) for more information. If the `read` system call returns less than one full block, then `dd` transfers a partial block. It still copies the specified number of blocks, so the total amount of transfered bytes is less than requested.

The warning about a “partial read” tells you exactly this: one of the reads was partial, so `dd` transfered an incomplete block. In the block counts, `+1` means that one block was read partially; since the output count is `+0`, all blocks were written out as read.

This doesn't affect the randomness of the data: all the bytes that `dd` writes out are bytes that it read from `/dev/urandom`. But you got fewer bytes than expected.

Linux's `/dev/urandom` accommodates arbitrary large requests (source: [`extract_entropy_user`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c?v=3.12#L1010) in `drivers/char/random.c`), so `dd` is normally safe when reading from it. However, reading large amounts of data takes time. If the process receives a signal, the `read` system call returns before filling its output buffer. This is normal behavior, and applications are supposed to call `read` in a loop; `dd` doesn't do this, for historical reasons (`dd`'s origins are murky, but it seems to have started out as a tool to access tapes, which have peculiar requirements, and was never adapted to be a general-purpose tool). When you check the progress, this sends the `dd` process a signal which interrupts the read. You have a choice between knowing how many bytes `dd` will copy in total (make sure not to interrupt it — no progress check, no suspension), or knowing how many bytes `dd` has copied so far, in which case you can't know how many more bytes it will copy.

The version of [`dd` in GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#dd-invocation) (as found on non-embedded Linux and on Cygwin) has a flag `fullblock` which tells `dd` to call `read` in a loop (and ditto for `write`) and thus always transfer full blocks. The error message suggests that you use it; you should always use it (in both input and output flags), except in very special circumstances (mostly when accessing tapes) — if you use `dd` at all, that is: there are usually better solutions (see below).

```
dd if=/dev/urandom iflag=fullblock of=file bs=1M count=1000000
```

Another possible way to be sure of what `dd` will do is to pass a block size of 1. Then you can tell how many bytes were copied from the block count, though I'm not sure what will happen if a `read` is interrupted before reading the first byte (which is not very likely in practice but can happen). However, even if it works, this is very slow.

The general advice on using `dd` is **do not use `dd`**. Although `dd` is often advertised as a low-level command to access devices, it is in fact no such thing: all the magic happens in the device file (the `/dev/…`) part, `dd` is just an ordinary tool with a high potential for misuse resulting in data loss. In most cases, there is a simpler and safer way to do what you want, at least on Linux.

For example, to read a certain number of bytes at the beginning of a file, just call `head`:

```
head -c 1000000m </dev/urandom >file
```

I made a quick benchmark on my machine and did not observe any performance difference between `dd` with a large block size and `head`.

If you need to skip some bytes at the beginning, pipe `tail` into `head`:

```
dd if=input of=output count=C bs=B seek=S
<input tail -c +$((S*B+1)) | head -c $((C*B)) >output
```

If you want to see progress, call `lsof` to see the file offset. This only works on a regular file (the output file on your example), not on a character device.

```
lsof -a -p 1234 -d 1
cat /proc/1234/fdinfo/1
```

You can call [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) to get a progress report (better than `dd`'s), at the expense of an additional item in the pipeline (performance-wise, it's barely perceptible).

Comment: +1. This is one of the most well-researched posts I have read on the StackExchange network in a long time. It is succinct yet contains all the detail (historic and present-day) about the `dd` command which I didn't realise I needed to know. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry but I disagree with your assertion that dd is a "cranky tool that is hard to use correctly" and "do not use dd".  It is a perfectly fine utility when used correctly by somebody who has taken the time to understand it.  Indeed disk forensic toolkits almost all depend on dd or a derivative such as dcfldd.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 GNU `dd` can be used safely, thanks to its `fullblock` option. But if you have GNU coreutils you don't need `dd` much. “Derivatives” such as `dcfldd` are *not* `dd`, they do not suffer from its design defects, so my answer does not apply to them. A vast, vast majority of people who use `dd` have not taken sufficient time to understand it (at most, they have taken the time to *think* they understand it) and the way they use it does lead to data loss.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 By the way, if you think you understand `dd`, please answer [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial). But before you post an answer, make sure that what you post actually works and actually applies to all `dd` versions across Unix variants, unlike the existing answers.

Comment: @Gilles So we shouldn't use "echo" b/c of its potential for misuse (sudo echo hello world > /dev/sda)?

Comment: @whitey04 I recommend not handling barrels of nitroglycerine. I did not say that you shouldn't use matches.

Comment: Example for the partial read: `{ printf a; sleep 1; printf b; } | dd bs=2 count=1 2>/dev/null | wc -c` prints 1 instead of 2.

Comment: @whitey04 your `sudo echo hello world > /dev/sda` unfortunately shows exactly how easy it is to misuse a command (either `sudo` wasn't necessary or the `>/dev/sda` would fail). The `dd` command is in a higher category of "misusability"

Comment: @roaima I'm an embedded developer; sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do.  Requirements can be stupid.

Answer (score 17):

The warning occurs when `dd` could not get enough data to fill a block in a single read. This happens with erratic or slow data sources, or sources that write data in smaller units than your requested blocksize.

There is no problem with data integrity, but the problem is that `dd` counts a partial read still as a read block.

If you are not using the `count` option, the warning hardly matters, it's just a performance consideration. But with `count`, you won't get the amount of data you requested. Due to partial reads, `of` will be smaller than `count*bs` at the end.

So when you use `count`, technically you should always use `iflag=fullblock` as well.

The `+x` should be the number of partial blocks.

Answer (score -5):

```
< /dev/urandom \
dd ibs=4k obs=64k |
dd bs=64k count=16000000 >file
```

^That will just work. The misinformation otherwise had here is manifestly false. `dd`'s buffers are *explicit* and so, to buffer input to *count* occurrences you need to explicitly buffer. That is all. Don't buy the fud.

Comment: Why would you want to pipe your data through two separate `dd` processes?  Is writing to `file` also expected to take a lot of CPU time, and you want to let those `write` system calls happen in parallel with the other dd's `read` systems call on urandom, which definitely are CPU-bound?  What does this get you that `head -c $((16000000 * 65536)) /dev/urandom > file` doesn't?