# How can I write the disk-image of a Linux computer with the "dd" command to another computer connected with a LAN cable?

Tags: linux, disk-image

I have a computer with Linux (A) and another computer with a formatted hard disk(B). If I connect two computers with LAN cable, how can I write the disk-image of computer A to computer B using the dd command?

Comment: see for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121983/30851 https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/132797/30851

Comment: @frostschutz Thanks. The other computer is formatted and has no operating system. Is it possible to connect with LAN cable in this case?

Comment: you'll have to boot a livecd/rescue system. it would also be possible to boot that over the network (like tftp / pxe boot) but not much point to set that up for a once off install ...

Comment: You can boot from a live drive in the computer without any internal operating system and then use Netcat `nc`. In Ubuntu you can do it according to [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2446699&p=13970279#post13970279). If it does not work for you, `nc` might be compiled in a different way or from a different version of source code, and you should find how to use it in `man nc` or `info nc`, or use Ubuntu live drives at both ends.