# What's the POSIX way to read an exact number of bytes from a file?

Tags: dd, posix, binary, head

Just hit this problem, and learned a lot from the chosen answer: [Create random data with dd and get "partial read warning". Is the data after the warning now really random?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121865/create-random-data-with-dd-and-get-partial-read-warning-is-the-data-after-the#121888)

Unfortunately the suggested solution `head -c` is not portable.

For folks who insist that `dd` is the answer, please carefully read the linked answer which explains in great detail why `dd` can not be the answer. Also, please observe this:

```
$ dd bs=1000000 count=10 if=/dev/random of=random
dd: warning: partial read (89 bytes); suggest iflag=fullblock
0+10 records in
0+10 records out
143 bytes (143 B) copied, 99.3918 s, 0.0 kB/s
$ ls -l random ; du -kP random
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 143 Apr 22 19:19 random
4       random
$ pwd
/tmp
```

Comment: `dd` is portable. If you don't mind the warning, or adjust your blocksize, is there a problem with using `dd`?

Comment: @muru OP referred to `head -c` not being portable.

Comment: @Guido yes, but `dd` is.

Comment: @muru `dd` doesn't do the job, for reasons explained in the linked answer. In my experiments, requesting 10 * 2^20 bytes with `dd` yields less than 200 bytes. If you don't understand or believe that, I urge you to read the linked answer which clearly explains how it can be so.

Comment: @LowPowah I did read the linked post and I understand it, but I wonder why you can't adjust your blocksize.

Comment: @muru Of course I can set the `bs=` parameter, but that doesn't prevent `dd` from returning before reading the requested number of bytes (n = bs * count).

Comment: Are you saying that you can't get the requested number of bytes for *any* value of `bs`?

Comment: @muru I am saying that `dd bs=1000000 count=10 if=/dev/random of=/tmp/random` results in a file containing less than 200 bytes. Now do you understand why `dd` isn't the right tool for the job?

Comment: No, I still don't get it. If that`bs` causes problems, why aren't you using a lower `bs`? Why not `dd bs=1000 count=10000`? Is something forcing you to use that `bs`?

Comment: @muru the only way to get a guaranteed number of bytes from `dd` is to either use a `bs` of 1 byte (as `read()` will return at least 1 byte) or to *not* use `bs=` and instead use `obs=` (and, optionally, `ibs=`) separately and pipe it into another `dd` with your count and an `ibs=` set to the `obs=` of the first. If you use `bs=` at all `dd` will write partial reads without buffering  them to a known size. Using `(i)bs=1000 count=10000` only guarantees 10k writes of *up to* 1000 bytes and will happily write out less than 10k * 1000 bytes if any of the reads return less.

Comment: @AdrianGünter which  still doesn't explain why OP can't use a `bs` of 1...

Comment: @muru Because `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1 count=10000000` takes far longer than with larger block sizes. It's simply not practical for many/most situations. Piping to another `dd` works and allows arbitrarily large reads and writes.

Comment: @AdrianGünter for all that, you haven't shown a concrete example for avoiding a 1b block size

Comment: @muru: Simplest - `dd if=/dev/random | dd count=128 | wc -c` will reliably write 64KiB on systems where `dd`'s default blocksize is 512 bytes. The blocksize can be adjusted by setting `obs=` on the first `dd` and `ibs=` (or just `bs=`) on the second to the same value: `dd if=/dev/random obs=4K | dd bs=4K count=16 | wc -c` also writes 64KiB. The key is to *never* set the `bs=` value on the first `dd` as this will ensure full output blocks are accumulated before writes. On some implementations you need to set `ibs=` of first to a value other than `obs=`: `dd if=... ibs=1K obs=4K | dd bs=4K ...`

Comment: @muru try `dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/null obs=1317` and let it run for 30 seconds or so on a system that isn't entropy starved, then kill it with `Ctrl-c`. If you read the status output as `[<full_blocks>+<partial_blocks>] records (in|out)` you will see that `dd` read in many (or entirely) partial blocks – many more blocks than it wrote – and that *every output block it wrote was a full block*, i.e., 1317 bytes. You can verify this with `dd if=/dev/random obs=1317 | pv -bn >/dev/null`; `pv` will report bytes read in multiples of 1,317.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, to manipulate the content of a binary file, `dd` is pretty much the only tool in POSIX. Although most modern implementations of text processing tools (`cat`, `sed`, `awk`, …) can manipulate binary files, this is not required by POSIX: some older implementations do choke on null bytes, input not terminated by a newline, or invalid byte sequences in the ambient character encoding.

It is possible, but difficult, to use `dd` safely. The reason I spend a lot of energy steering people away from it is that there's a lot of advice out there that promotes `dd` in situations where it is neither useful nor safe.

The problem with `dd` is its notion of blocks: it assumes that a call to [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) returns one block; if `read` returns less data, you get a partial block, which throws things like `skip` and `count` off. Here's an example that illustrates the problem, where `dd` is reading from a pipe that delivers data relatively slowly:

```
yes hello | while read line; do echo $line; done | dd ibs=4 count=1000 | wc -c
```

On a bog-standard Linux (Debian jessie, Linux kernel 3.16, `dd` from GNU coreutils 8.23), I get a highly variable number of bytes, ranging from about 3000 to almost 4000. Change the input block size to a divisor of 6, and the output is consistently 4000 bytes as one would naively expect — the input to `dd` arrives in bursts of 6 bytes, and as long as a block doesn't span multiple bursts, `dd` gets to read a complete block.

This suggests a solution: **use an input block size of 1**. No matter how the input is produced, there's no way for `dd` to read a partial block if the input block size is 1. (This is not completely obvious: `dd` could read a block of size 0 if it's interrupted by a signal — but if it's interrupted by a signal, the `read` system call returns -1. A `read` returning 0 is only possible if the file is opened in non-blocking mode, and in that case a `read` had better not be considered to have been performed at all. In blocking mode, `read` only returns 0 at the end of the file.)

```
dd ibs=1 count="$number_of_bytes"
```

The problem with this approach is that it can be slow (but not shockingly slow: only about 4 times slower than `head -c` in my quick benchmark).

POSIX defines other tools that read binary data and convert it to a text format: [`uuencode`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uuencode.html) (outputs in historical uuencode format or in Base64), [`od`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/od.html) (outputs an octal or hexadecimal dump). Neither is well-suited to the task at hand. `uuencode` can be undone by [`uudecode`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uudecode.html), but counting bytes in the output is awkward because the number of bytes per line of output is not standardized. It's possible to get well-defined output from `od`, but unfortunately there's no POSIX tool to go the other way round (it can be done but only through slow loops in sh or awk, which defeats the purpose here).

Comment: Thank you for a very comprehensive answer. It seems like there is no simple, and safe way which is also portable. Maybe the answer is to write a C program if one  wants to work with arbitrary bytes in units smaller than lines. I am intrigued by the possibility of a uuencode/uudecode solution. Can you please explain a little more why such a solution would not be safe or portable? (I'm defining *safe* to mean guaranteed not to lose data on given that everything else works perfectly.)

Comment: @LowPowah `uuencode` won't lose data, the problem is counting the input bytes. You can easily count the number of lines, but the number of bytes per line is not standardized. You can pipe into awk and do the counting there, but if you do that I think you'll lose any speed advantage. Furthermore the output of `uuencode` (in either format) can't easily be split according to input bytes, since it processes bytes by blocks. The output of `od` is easy to work with but difficult to convert back to binary afterwards.

Comment: On my system `ibs=1` with 7.9 MB of data degrades the performance from 62 MB/s down to 2.4 MB/s.

Comment: `od -An -vtx1 -N10` would read 10 bytes and be POSIX.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, but it also encodes those bytes. Sure, you can pipe the output to an awk program that will decode them (or can you? I don't remember if awk can portably output null bytes), but that's not really helpful here.

Answer (score 8):

Newer versions of the GNU implementation of `dd` have a `count_bytes` iflag.  eg:

```
cat /dev/zero | dd count=1234 iflag=count_bytes | wc -c
```

will output something like

```
2+1 records in
2+1 records out
1234 bytes (1.2 kB, 1.2 KiB) copied, 0.000161684 s, 7.6 MB/s
1234
```

Answer (score -2):

Part of the point of using `dd` at all is that the user gets to pick the block size it uses. If `dd` fails for too large block sizes, IMO it's the user's responsibility to try smaller block sizes. I could ask for a TB from `dd` in one block, but that doesn't mean I'll get it.

If you want an exact number of bytes, this will be horrendously slow, but should work:

```
dd bs=1 count=1000000
```

If even a block size of `1` results in partial reads, …