# Can I read a single character from stdin in POSIX shell?

Tags: shell-script, posix, portability

Only `read -r` is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html); `read -n NUM`, used to read `NUM` characters, is not. Is there a portable way to automatically return after reading a given number of characters from stdin?

My usecase is printing prompts like this:

```
Do the thing? [y/n]
```

If possible, I'd like to have the program automatically proceed after typing `y` or `n`, without needing the user to press enter afterwards.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Reading one character means reading one byte at a time until you get a full character.

To read one byte with the POSIX toolchest, there's `dd bs=1 count=1`.

Note however reading from a terminal device, when that device is in `icanon` mode (as it generally is by default), only ever returns when you press <kbd>Return</kbd> (a.k.a. <kbd>Enter</kbd>), because until then the terminal device driver implements a form of line editor that allows you to use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or other editing characters to amend what you enter, and what you enter is made available to the reading application only when you submit that line you've been editing (with <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).

For that reason, `ksh`'s `read -n/N` or `zsh`'s `read -k`, when they detect stdin is a terminal device, put that device out of the `icanon` mode, so that bytes are available to read as soon as they are sent by the terminal.

Now note that `ksh`'s `read -n n` only reads *up* to `n` characters *from a single line*, it still stops when a newline character is read (use `-N n` to read `n` characters). `bash`, contrary ksh93, still does IFS and backslash processing for both `-n` and `-N`.

To mimic `zsh`'s `read -k` or `ksh93`'s `read -N1` or `bash`'s `IFS= read -rN 1`, that is, read one and only one character from stdin, POSIXly:

```
readc() { # arg: <variable-name>
  if [ -t 0 ]; then
    # if stdin is a tty device, put it out of icanon, set min and
    # time to sane value, but don't otherwise touch other input or
    # or local settings (echo, isig, icrnl...). Take a backup of the
    # previous settings beforehand.
    saved_tty_settings=$(stty -g)
    stty -icanon min 1 time 0
  fi
  eval "$1="
  while
    # read one byte, using a work around for the fact that command
    # substitution strips trailing newline characters.
    c=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2> /dev/null; echo .)
    c=${c%.}

    # break out of the loop on empty input (eof) or if a full character
    # has been accumulated in the output variable (using "wc -m" to count
    # the number of characters).
    [ -n "$c" ] &&
      eval "$1=\${$1}"'$c
        [ "$(($(printf %s "${'"$1"'}" | wc -m)))" -eq 0 ]'; do
    continue
  done
  if [ -t 0 ]; then
    # restore settings saved earlier if stdin is a tty device.
    stty "$saved_tty_settings"
  fi
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure a sanity check is required, but as there's an `eval`, I'd do something like `__varname_check() { case "$1" in [!_a-zA-Z]*) echo BAD;; *[_a-zA-Z0-9]*) echo BAD ;; esac; }`, test as follows: `__varname_check "__0kay"; __varname_check "0bad; __varname_check ")bad"`

Comment: EOF only happens with icanon. With -icanon dd reads char ^D instead of getting EOF.

Comment: @giraffes, `dd` would also reach eof (even if that's with `read()` returning `EIO` rather than 0 bytes) if the terminal is disconnected (and SIGHUP is ignored) for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27875395) ... this works for me with bash:

```
echo -n "Is this a good question (y/n)? "
old_stty_cfg=$(stty -g)
stty raw -echo ; answer=$(head -c 1) ; stty $old_stty_cfg # Careful playing with stty
if echo "$answer" | grep -iq "^y" ;then
    echo Yes
else
    echo No
fi
```

Comment: That works if you have `head -c`, but [it's not strictly POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/head.html#tag_20_57_18) (unless that's being changed). See: [What's the POSIX way to read an exact number of bytes from a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/278443/170373). Bash also isn't very strictly POSIX, even if you call it as `sh`. `dash` and `busybox`'s `sh` are probably closer (they are easy to get to if you're on Linux). Though that one works in `sh`, too. (but you should probably quote `"$old_stty_cfg"` just out of principle.)

Comment: @ilkkachu: `dash` and `busybox` both do not support multi byte characters and thus are not POSIX compliant. If you like a minimal POSIX shell, you should look at `pbosh`, a compile variant of `bosh` that is close to the features of `dash` but supports multi-byte characters.

Comment: @schily, I said "closer [than Bash]", not "exactly compliant". Bash has extensions that are active even in POSIX mode, which makes it rather hard to use as a yardstick, esp. given that ksh extensions are rather commonly known. Also, I don't think multibyte support of the shell matters much for that particular script. (The fact that `head -c` counts bytes and not characters in at least GNU and FreeBSD does matter, but it's not the shell's fault, is it.)

Comment: @ilkkachu: `pbosh` tries to avoid POSIX extensions, this is why it is useful as a shell to test for POSIX compliance of scripts. If you like to be shure that a script is really portable, you would still need to test a script with `bash` as well as it implements pipes different where POSIX allows both variants. BTW: You see the problems with `dash` if you set `IFS=ö` in UTF-8 mode and `head -c` is indeed non-portable.

Comment: Also, `printf` is specified by POSIX; `echo -n` isn’t.

Comment: You need to reread POSIX: POSIX specifies very well how -n works, since a shell on a real POSIX system (in contrast to a shell on a small embedded system) needs to be `XSI` compliant.

Answer (score -3):

Other solution with dd:

```
key=$(stty -icanon; dd ibs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null)
```

Comment: In most shells, that would leave terminal with `-icanon`. The subshell there doesn't help to reset it.