# dd bs=X count=1 reads less than X bytes

Tags: dd, io, streams

I have `dd` from GNU coreutils 8.32.

When I run `{ echo a; sleep 1; echo b; } | dd bs=4 count=1` then I get

```
a
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
2 bytes copied, 2.0381e-05 s, 98.1 kB/s
```

`dd` terminates during the `sleep` even though the block size was not reached and there was no `EOF`. The output `b\n` is lost. This does not happen if I remove either `sleep` or `count=1`.

In `man dd` I couldn't find anything that describes this behavior.

1. Why doesn't `dd count=1` wait till `bs` is reached or an `EOF` is encountered?
2. How can I force `dd` to wait?

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121865/315749

Comment: [When is dd suitable for copying data? (or, when are read() and write() partial)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't caused by dd's behaviour but operating system specific behaviour.  That said it is behaviour [specified by posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html).

> The value returned may be less than nbyte if the number of bytes left in the file is less than nbyte, if the read() request was interrupted by a signal, or **if the file is a pipe or FIFO or special file and has fewer than nbyte bytes immediately available** for reading. For example, a read() from a file associated with a terminal may return one typed line of data.

When you set `bs=4` you instruct `dd` to read 4 bytes at a time, but that only means it requests 4 bytes per `read()`.  Of the OS returns less, `dd` won't go back and `read()` a second time unless...

There is the `iflag=fullblock` which instructs `dd` to perform multiple `read()` operations to read an entire block.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a bit. Even though the [specification of `dd`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) does not talk about such details. That `dd` happens to use `read()` the way it is seems more like a implementation detail we shouldn't be concerned about.

Comment: Anyways, since `fullblock` is not specified by posix, do you have any posix conform alternatives? I thought about `dd bs=1 count=X` instead of `dd bs=X count=1 iflag=fullblock`. In my tests this worked (albeit being far less efficient). If I understood correctly, `read()` blocks until there is at least one byte of input, right?

Comment: @Socowi no it won't return 0 unless less it's a non-blocking read which it shouldn't be.  I'm afraid I don't have a posix alternative.  You might want to check if BSD and Busybox both support that flag.  Sometimes there are non-posix flags which are very common anyway.

Comment: @Socowi, and Philip, it's all about how `dd` behaves, and how it's specified. Right there in the POSIX text, second sentence: _"It shall read the input one block at a time, using the specified input block size; it shall then process the block of data actually returned, which could be smaller than the requested block size."_ It's not like e.g. `tail -c`, which just reads a particular amount of bytes. So, unless you want that block-based behaviour, you probably shouldn't use `dd`. `head -c` isn't in POSIX, but it's rather common, and definitely exists in GNU.

Comment: @ilkkachu yes I feel this is hiding something in plain sight.  Many users believe that bs * count = total data transferred. If it doesn't, and the same behaviour can be observed when reading from regular files then this invalidates a lot of advice about dd's behaviour.

Comment: @PhilipCouling, it doesn't mean _x*y_ bytes, it means _x_ blocks of _y_ bytes. That makes a difference at least with some tape drives... See [Gilles's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121888/170373) and [mikeserv's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192114/170373) answers to the linked questions. But OTOH, you wouldn't see it on regular files, usually. You could, in principle, but I have the impression that it would really be an exception to see short read or write from something backed by a regular filesystem. Except if there's some IO error, of course, but then you have bigger problems.

Comment: @ilkkachu we are agreed on what dd really does.  I was pointing out there's a tonne of tutorials and very many answers here that assume it calculates total read, and corrections on that point are almost never seen...  As for regular files, no that's not correct. I've run into this when performing unbuffered python reads even on small files.  If the read crosses a block boundary and the next block isn't in the disk cache yet, Linux seems to return whatever it has in cache and underread.  So even healthy NVME drives may do this.

Comment: @ilkkachu try reading a tonne of largish files (mb+) in units of a large prime number. Use the language of your choice and see if you get underreads.

Comment: @PhilipCouling yeah, well, I did start getting the tingle of having to test that when I said it. `dd bs=12345701 < bigfile2 > /dev/null` just gives me 76+1 in and out. Or, `perl -l -e '$n = sysread STDIN, $buf, 123456761; print STDERR $n; $m = syswrite STDOUT, $buf, $n; print STDERR $m' < bigfile2 > out` prints `123456761` twice. On ext4 and tmpfs. Odder filesystems might be different. I was thinking if NFS could be a problem. Esp. if the network hiccups, but I don't think I can test that now.

Comment: @ilkkachu when I hit this, I was transferring about 1TB.  My code errored out around 200GB because of an underread (I'd put a check in to be sure).  It's not a *common* occurrence. But it does happen under normal circumstances.

Comment: @PhilipCouling, oh hmm, what, I missed that part about python. I thought I read that comment though. What do unbuffered reads mean here? Not `O_DIRECT`? With that, I would not be at all surprised. But, anyway, if it happens even normally, then so be it.

Comment: @ilkkachu if you don't know python then just think "read()".  Default python has it's own buffer which normally hides this issue.

Comment: @PhilipCouling, reads on a normal file in Linux ( pretty much all operating systems actually ) will only return what is currently in the cache if you put it in non blocking mode.  It's always been that way; short reads are just not something you have to deal with unless you work with pipes or sockets.

Comment: @psusi, but the Linux man page for open(2) says of O_NONBLOCK: _"Note that this flag has no effect for regular files and block devices; that is, I/O operations will (briefly) block when  device  activity  is required, regardless of whether O_NONBLOCK is set."_ Would be interesting to test on other systems, though.