# Why does dd create a 34MB file with bs=1G?

Tags: filesystems, dd

When typing the command:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=outputfile bs=1G count=1
```

I should receive a file at the size of 1GB if I understand correctly.

Yet, I receive a file of the following values:

```
33554431 bytes (34 MB, 32 MiB) copied, 0.27126 s, 124 MB/s
```

Why is that?

On the system where it works I receive:

```
1+0 Records in
1+0 Records out
```

Where the file ends up with 34MB I receive:

```
0+1 Records in
0+1 Records out
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create random data with dd and get "partial read warning". Is the data after the warning now really random?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121865/create-random-data-with-dd-and-get-partial-read-warning-is-the-data-after-the)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The device `/dev/urandom` temporarily returned zero bytes (no more data). The `dd` utility treated that as EOF and stopped. Since you know that `/dev/urandom` will generate more random data you need to tell `dd` to reattempt reading input:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom iflag=fullblock bs=1G count=1
```

The `iflag=fullblock` flag is also needed when reading from tools such as `zcat` that write data in non-block-sized units.