# dd remove range of bytes

Tags: shell-script, dd

Given this file

```
$ cat hello.txt
hello doge world
```

I would like to remove a range of bytes to end up with this

```
$ cat hello.txt
heorld
```

I would like to do this with `dd` if possible. The reason is because I am
already using `dd` to overwrite bytes in this manner

```
printf '\x5E' | dd conv=notrunc of=hello.txt bs=1 seek=$((0xE))
```

I prefer to write back to the same file, but a different output file would be
okay.

Comment: Do you have a recent version of GNU `dd`? If so, you can seek the input and output with byte granularity, so a modified version of [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121798/49439) followed by a call to `truncate` to shorten the file ought to work.

Comment: A word of warning: if you overwrite the existing file and your system crashes half-way through, the file will be in an unusable state: you'll have no way to know which part has already been moved and which part hasn't. There is a reason why most tools are geared towards creating new files!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a matter of specifying blocksize, count, and skip:

```
$ cat hello.txt
hello doge world
$ { dd bs=1 count=2 ; dd skip=3 bs=1 count=1 ; dd skip=6 bs=1 ; } <hello.txt 2>/dev/null
he orld
```

The above uses three invocations of `dd`.  The first gets the first two characters `he`.  The second skips to the end of `hello` and copies the space which follows.  The third skips into the last word `world` copying all but its first character.

This was done with [GNU `dd`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html) but [BSD `dd`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dd&sektion=1) looks like it should work also.

Answer (score 5):

```sh
# copy the end piece into correct position
dd bs=1 seek=2 skip=12 conv=notrunc if=hello.txt of=hello.txt

# truncate
dd bs=1 seek=6 if=/dev/null of=hello.txt
```

[Mark is right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128871#comment206593_128871)

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is possible using `dd` but that's kind of like using a tank to kill a fly. Why not

```
$ printf "%s %s\n" $(head -c 2 hello.txt) $(tail -c 5 hello.txt )
he orld
```

The `-c` option means (for `head`):

```
   -c, --bytes=[-]K
          print the first K bytes of each  file;  with  the  leading  '-',
          print all but the last K bytes of each file
```

and for `tail`:

```
   -c, --bytes=K
          output the last K bytes; alternatively,  use  -c  +K  to  output
          bytes starting with the Kth of each file
```

In general, to remove the byte range *n* to *x* inclusive, you would run

```
( head -c n-1; head -c -x-1)  )
```

For example, to remove the 4th through 12th bytes:

```
$ (head -c 3 hello.txt; tail -c +11 hello.txt )
hel world
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl `pack` and `unpack` function is goot at dealing with fixed-width string. If you want to use `Perl`, try this:

```
$ perl -le '
    ($head,$skip,$tail) = unpack("A2 A5 A*", "hello world");
    ($space) = $skip =~ m/(\s+)/;
    print $head.$space.$tail;
'
he orld
```

**Explanation**

- We will divide string to three parts, `$head` is start of string until the first byte we want to remove, `$skip` is the range of bytes we want to remove, `$tail` is the rest of string.
- `unpack` template `"A2 A5 A*"` will divide the string to three parts as explained above.
- With `$skip`, we will get any spaces in it, save it to `$space`.
- Print the concatenation of three parts to get desired output.

**Updated**

Since you don't want to save the space, the solution seems to be easier:

```
$ perl -le 'print unpack("A2 x5 A*","hello world")'
heorld
```

With updated string:

```
$ perl -le 'print unpack("A2 x10 A*","hello doge world")'
heorld
```

`x10` in `unpack` template meaning skip the 10 bytes in string.