# Use dd to extract a precise portion of a file?

Tags: files, dd, binary

I have a 588Ko file, and I want to extract bytes from 0x7E8D6 to 0x8AD5D.
I tried : 
 `dd if=file of=result bs=50311 count=1 skip=518358`

- 50311 stands for 0x8AD5D - 0x7E8D6
- 518358 stands for 0x7E8D6 (from where I want to cut)

dd tells me that it can't skip to the specified offset.
What can I do? Is there any other utility to do it?

Comment: `dd iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes skip=518358 count=50311` or `dd iflag=fullblock bs=518358 skip=1 count=1` and then `truncate`.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121794/read-the-middle-of-a-large-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`skip` and `count` are both expressed in blocks. You're asking to skip 518358 × 50311 bytes.

[`dd` can let errors go undetected](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial), so it's best avoided anyway.

With most Unix variants (including BusyBox but not OpenSBD), you can pass a number of bytes to `head` and `tail`. Just remember that `tail` counts from 1.

```
<file tail -c "$((0x7E8D6 + 1))" | head -c "$((0x8AD5D - 0x7E8D6))" >result
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. May you please explain what is the first `<` for?

Comment: @Nofix It's an [input redirection](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). If you're reading from a file, you can pass its name as an argument to `tail` instead.

Answer (score 5):

**Use dd to extract a precise portion of a file?**

Lets adjust your syntax a little bit.

`bs=1`

Set the block size to one because of any count or skip you want to be in single blocks or bytes.

`skip=518358`

Skip this many blocks or bytes at the beginning of the stream.

`count=50311`

Copy this many blocks or bytes from the stream.

`dd if=/path/file of=/path/result bs=1 count=50311 skip=518358`