# Artificially prime buffer cache?

Tags: linux, performance, io, cache, buffer

Is it beneficial to artificially prime the buffer cache when dealing with larger files?

Here's a scenario: A large file needs to be processed, line by line. Conceptually, it is easy to parallelize the task to saturate a multi-core machine. However, since the the lines need to be read first (before distributing them to workers round-robin), the overall process becomes IO-bound and therefore slower.

Is it reasonable to read all or portions of the file into the buffer cache in advance to have faster read times, when the actual processing occurs?

---

Update: I wrote a small [front-end](https://github.com/miku/rarara) to the `readahead` system call. Trying to add some benchmark later...

Comment: benchmark, otherwise it is just opinion based ;) but i'd just use http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html and read it it like you normally would

Comment: @UlrichDangel, thanks for the readahead link, didn't knew about this syscall.

Comment: just a headsup, if you use `mmap`, you can use `madvise` to mark it as sequential read so the kernel will do the readaehead as well and discard old pages. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html

Comment: @UlrichDangel, thanks again. I found a simple POSIX-compliant answer, namely [dd](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html).

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way as you depend on an external program (figuring out bs/count etc.) For a while there was an optimisation in dd which just returned if of was /dev/null. How about using `posix_fadvise` instead? This should be posix compliant and still achieve the same result without relying on dd

Comment: Great advice, I'll try to see, if I can implement these various approaches...

Answer (score 0):

To prime the cache with a whole file:

```
cat big.file >/dev/null
```

To prime the cache with a portion of a file, as per [this comment](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/2axv21/tiny_tool_to_prime_buffer_cache_for_a_file/cizvdlf):

```
time dd if=big.file of=/dev/null bs=1024k count=XXX skip=YYY
```

Example 2.5G file:

```
$ time rarara big.file 0 2459650481
real    0m13.803s

$ sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

$ time dd if=big.file of=/dev/null bs=4096 count=600501 skip=0
real    0m14.394s
```

Comment: JFTR you should clear the buffers between running these commands.  I think this testcase is also rather artificial, I'd evaluate it within your environment to see how many operations/second you can achieve via which method. (Do not forget to clear the buffer/cache between runs)

Comment: @UlrichDangel, I did `drop_caches`, just forgot to mention it.

Comment: It isn't clear what your example is supposed to demonstrate. That `dd` with a small block size is smaller than `rarara`? A small block size makes reading artificially [slower](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492). How does this compare with not priming the cache at all? Linux already has read-ahead as a kernel feature, and it's often counterproductive to try to second-guess it.

Comment: @Gilles: I guess the example does not convey too much, maybe just this: that filling the buffer cache with a dedicated syscall is a bit faster than `dd` (difference gets larger with bigger files). As for "Linux already has read-ahead as a kernel feature" - when does it read-ahead? When I start to read a large file sequentially - or when certain access patterns occur? I am thankful for any hints, pointers or resources on this.