# Resuming a DD of an entire disk

Tags: dd

I'm overwriting my hard drive with random data using the good old `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/disk/by-uuid/etc bs=512
```

It's a 2TB array and my MacBook (running Linux, ok?) can only write data at around 3.7MB/s, which is pretty pathetic as I've seen my desktop at home do 20MB/s. When I go home tonight, I'd like to stop the `dd` run here, take it home, and see what kind of progress can be made overnight with a more powerful machine.

I've been monitoring the progress using a simple loop:

```
while true; do kill -USR1 $PID ; sleep 10 ; done
```

The output looks like this:

```
464938971+7 records in
464938971+7 records out
238048755782 bytes (238 GB) copied, 64559.6 s, 3.7 MB/s
```

If I were to resume the `dd` pass at home, how would I restart it? I'm aware of the `seek` parameter, but what do I point it to, the record number or the byte count?

Comment: Do I use the record number? Does that equal the block written count?

Comment: The number of blocks = total bytes / block size, in theory it should be 238048755782 / 512 = 464938976 but you have some partial records there so I would  subtract a few blocks from the number just to be safe, e.g. `seek=464938960`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @don_crissti already commented, just use `seek=` to resume.

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/disk/by-uuid/etc bs=512 seek=464938971
```

`GNU dd` also supports seeking in bytes, so you can resume exactly, regardless of blocksize:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/disk/by-uuid/etc bs=1M \
   seek=238048755782 oflag=seek_bytes
```

A larger blocksize should help with speeds even for a slow device like `/dev/urandom`.

If you are looking for faster alternatives, you could `cryptsetup plainOpen` with a random key and zero that, it should beat `/dev/urandom` by an order of magnitude (without AES-NI) or even run at full speed (with AES-NI).

You could also use `shred -n 1` if pseudorandom data is good enough for your use case. `shred` should be able to utilize the full disk speed, even on a very slow machine.

Comment: I didn't know about `plainOpen` until now. Great! Finished my scrambling of a 2TB drive in around 4 hours as opposed to 256GB in over 12 using `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: When i was running the dd through pipe | gzip -1 - | i am guessing i can not know where to resume on destination file right?

Comment: @16851556 you'd have to [determine the exact byte count inside gzip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/546483/30851) and then either append gzip to gzip ; or,  make a separate file and use seek on resume

Answer (score 8):

Just a reminder for people who would like to copy rather than just randomizing disks (which is not *that* common) : you can use `skip=BLOCKS` to start *reading* at the proper position, and `seek=BLOCKS` to start *writing* at the correct position. Both options use blocks, not bytes. When breaking/restarting, it's advisable to remove a bunch of blocks just in case. It is usually worth raising the `bs` value above 512, as you can reach better performance if you read a lot of data in a row.

In your case, it is indeed a block value that you need to pass to `seek`. Maybe you should try to adjust `bs` to see if you can enhance speed, as `/dev/random` should go fast (pseudo-random and non-blocking when it has no entropy available)

Answer (score 4):

#### Cloning a disk:

Expanding on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180344/176886) answer from this thread, this is how one might go about cloning a whole disk and resuming:

This example is optimized for copying from a 5400rpm rotary drive to an SSD on a specific system.  `gdd` represents `GNU dd`:

```
> sudo gdd 'if=/dev/rdisk3' 'of=/dev/rdisk6' bs=4M status=progress
247426187264 bytes (247 GB, 230 GiB) copied, 2082 s, 119 MB/s
59012+0 records in
59011+0 records out
247510073344 bytes (248 GB, 231 GiB) copied, 2082.92 s, 119 MB/s
```

I can resume this in one of two ways:

```
> sudo gdd 'if=/dev/rdisk3' 'of=/dev/rdisk6' \
bs=4M \
seek=59011 skip=59011 \
status=progress
```

Or:

```
> sudo gdd 'if=/dev/rdisk3' 'of=/dev/rdisk6' \
bs=4M \
seek=247510073344 skip=247510073344 \
oflag=seek_bytes iflag=skip_bytes \
status=progress
```

In the first example, the reason we use `59011` and not `59012`, is because `59011` is how many block sized records were fully copied before being interrupted. (records out).

Answer (score 0):

`dd` with a tiny block size like 512 bytes is likely to be a lot slower than your disk's maximum throughput. Use a higher block size (on a hunch I'd say a few MB) for good performance. Or use `cat` — on Linux [I found `cat` to be as fast as `dd` with the optimal block size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492) when a single disk was involved (I don't know if that holds for OSX as well).

To find how far `cat` has reached, run [`lsof -p1234`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsof.8.html) where 1234 is the process ID of the `cat` process.

To resume from a position, use

```
{ dd bs=1 seek=123456; cat /dev/urandom; } >/dev/disk/…
```

where 123456 is the offset in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use

```
#ddrescue from to logfile
ddrescue /dev/sda /dev/sdb logfile
```

Keep the logfile off either the from or the to... and if you have to hit ctrl-c or something, ddrescue will read its own logfile and automatically resume.  It also copies everything easy first, and since it can resume from the logfile, you can tell it to "go back and try harder" for the others.