# dd'ing SDD, decreasing write speed

Tags: dd, ssd

My hard drive is a [SanDisk SSD](http://www.sandisk.com/products/ssd/sata/standard/). The drive is new. I've booted into ArchLinux Live System, with the intention of [preparing the hard drive for full disk encryption](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Drive_preparation#dm-crypt_wipe_before_installation). I've noticed a significant drop of write speed over time, see image:

[image: ...]

The same issue can also be observed when `dd`'ing directly from `/dev/zero` to `/dev/sda`.

Is this a usual behavior when `dd`'ing SSDs? Is there a wrong setting in the configuration/BIOS? Or is the SSD broken?

Answer (score 1):

While some performance loss is to be expected when filling an SSD entirely with random data, I don't know what's going on with your particular model.

[The blocksize you chose for `dd` is far too large](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183920/30851); but I'd be suprised if it was the cause of performance drops as severe as you're seeing.

Will you be using TRIM (`cryptsetup --allow-discards`)? If so, it's pointless to overwrite it like this, and the only preparation you need is `blkdiscard`. In most encryption setups, the real security issues are elsewhere. [Here's what a encrypted&trimmed SSD looks like.](https://bpaste.net/raw/505157)

Comment: I doubt that 16MB would be far from optimal for the block size. Anyway a block size that's too high only really hurts when both input and output are doing I/O (or when the block size gets to be a sizable fraction of RAM), which isn't the case here.