# stat file system sizes

Tags: linux, stat

With `stat 8.13` on a Debian based Linux - among many others - the following FORMAT directives (`--format=`) are offered:

In combination with `--file-system` (`-f`):

- `%s` Block size (for faster transfers)
- `%S` Fundamental block size (for block counts)

**Question(s)**: What exactly is meant?

My best guess is that `%s`, `%S` equals `%b` (display in Blocks) and `%B` (display block's size),  where the latter are for files and the first two are for file systems. Is that correct?

Comment: Consider making the part about `%s` and `%S` a separate question, since the question don_crissti linked to seems to answer the first of your two questions perfectly.

Comment: If you'd searched for "stat" questions, you'd already have an answer for your question about `%f`.  Thanks for narrowing the scope to `%s` and `%S`.  That makes the question more useful and easier to search.  I've retracted my close as duplicate vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   %S     fundamental block size (for block counts)
```

tells you how big each block is on the file system.  On most file systems, this is the smallest amount of space any file can take up.  Each file uses a multiple of this.

For example,

```
$ echo > a           # create a file containing a single byte
$ du -h a            # see how much disk space it's using
4.0K    a
$ stat -f -c '%S' .  # see what stat thinks the block size is
4096
$ tune2fs -l /dev/mydrive | grep '^Block size'
4096
```

I'm not 100% sure it always works like this.  For example, I expect it could also decide to print `512` or `1024`, even if the underlying block size is different, provided `stat -c %b FILE` * `stat -f -c %S FILE` = `du --block-size=1 FILE`.  The exact implementation would depend on the file system.

---

```
%s     block size (for faster transfers)
```

suggests how many bytes you should read at a time if you're copying large files, for example what you should use as the `bs` (blocksize) parameter when using `dd`.  But on the systems I checked, it always prints `4096`, even where larger values might be faster.  See [Is there a way to determine the optimal value for the bs parameter to dd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd) for more discussion of that.

---

Technically, this information (and all the information from `stat -f`) comes from the `statvfs` system call.

`%s` corresponds to the `f_bsize` field, and `%S` is `f_frsize`.

So you could look into their precise meanings starting with [the statvfs man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statvfs.2.html)

```
 unsigned long  f_bsize;    /* Filesystem block size */
 unsigned long  f_frsize;   /* Fragment size */
```

Comment: I wanted to confirm the difference between `f_bsize` and `f_frsize` for this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463312/getting-block-size-via-df-vs-dumpe2fs/463322#463322 , I ended up doing some digging here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463369/what-can-f-bsize-be-used-for-is-it-similar-to-st-blksize/