# osx - dd command behaving weirdly

Tags: command-line, osx, dd

I've been using `dd` for a couple of years now, most of the time successfully. I usually use it to `dd` Linux images to USB drives. My workflow doing so is as such:

1. convert `.iso` image to a `.img` format using `hdiutil convert -format UDRW output.img input.iso`
2. unmount the drive using `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskX`
3. `dd` the image to the drive using `dd if=./image.img of=/dev/rdiskX bs=1m`

Lately, and namely since I upgraded to Yosemite, `dd` has been showing some weird behavior. When I specify the block-size flag (`bs=1m`), it quits after about a minute, showing the default successful write message with the numbers of records in/out and bytes transferred and all that. What you would expect on a successful write. The problem is, it writes just a very small part of the image, then quits.

When I do not specify the block-size flag `dd` behaves as expected, writing the image to the disk in the ordinary fashion. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo.

Comment: Use [`obs=1m`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192114/52934)

Comment: Use `cat`. Not only is it guaranteed not to drop bytes randomly, [it may even be faster](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492).