# Does dd copy everything, including all metadata and all "empty" blocks

Tags: dd, block-device

Suddenly something was messed up with my partitions, or just one partition. I have a default Ubuntu installation, on a Kingston SSD, with the root file system encrypted with LUKS, (using AES I think). Now I'm trying to mount the partition from a live cd, but without luck.

I am so afraid of doing some additional harm that can not be undone. So I would like to make an *exact copy* of the drive. That means all partiton tables, whatever kind of metadata for the LUKS partition, and well any other kind of metadata that I don't know of. I guess I want all the empty blocks too, to feel absolutely safe.

I know about `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`, but I don't know if it will include all the data described.

Perhaps I need to specify block size with `-b`, but I don't understand how that works and why it is necessary (if it is). And I also don't know how to find the block size of the partition.

Please tell me if it does copy *all* data, and if not, if there is another way.

Comment: Not trying to be mean here, but where do you think metadata could be stored, other than the persistent storage? The term you are looking for is "disk cloning", btw.

Comment: You mean creature ;) I did not believe it was stored anywhere else than the drive, but maybe somewhere on the disk that is somehow not "represented" in /dev/sda. Perhaps the first 1kB or so is not considered "real data" (or whatever), and /dev/sda begins after that 1kB. Low level has surprised me in the past.

Comment: Alright, I understand it. Fortunately you can expect the device files in Linux to be your interface to the raw data, i.e., the data without the notion of "files", contained on the disks and `dd` to be Swiss army knife that deals with it. Best of luck!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it does, even the blocks that would not (officially) contain data and also all information regarding partitions, UUIDs, etc..

E.g. recovery of data (i.e. after deleting files) from the dd-copied drive would be possible.

You may want to read [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_cloning#Cloning_an_entire_hard_disk) regarding the `noerror` and `sync` options.

Block size (`bs=`) doesn't affect the result unless there are read errors, but you should set it to "1M" (or at least "4k") or it will take longer for no good reason.

Comment: And about block size. Does it matter?

Comment: Not likely, no. From what I understand your disk isn't defective, so you'll probably not run into read errors. A larger block size will just speed up the process. This is basically what Fiximan said.

Comment: @BenjaminB. A 1M block size is inefficient. `dd` has to spend more time copying from dev>mem/mem>dev than necessary. And if the block dev *is* failing and there *are* read errors, then that block size will not only slow the operation, but also contribute to *more* lost data per short read. Best - depending on source/taget devs and system kernel - is usually somewhere in the 32K-256K realm.

Comment: @mikeserv: Ah! Now that I read your answer below, your comment makes sense. I didn't know it was possible and safe to use `cp` for cloning block devices. Thanks for that!

Comment: @BenjaminB. Not that it much matters, but I think it a little strange - if the answer is worth a thanks, is it not worth a vote? Also... how does the comment about `dd` block-size relate to the answer about `cp` ?

Comment: @mikeserv: fishing for upvotes ay? ;) It relates to it because my first reaction to your comment was: "if 1M block sizes are inefficient, just increase it 100M", which is probably not what you meant. Your comment about 1M being inefficient is vague, because it doesn't state why that would be so. A larger block size *is* more efficient if you use `dd` (period). The explanation is in your answer: don't use a buffer at all (like `dd`), but simply copy disk-to-disk using `cp`.

Comment: @BenjaminB. - larger block sizes are *not* more efficient. This is because the disk can/will only serve up so much data at a time anyway, and `dd` has to store that in memory between read/write. Tiny block sizes are *also* inefficient because rather than storing too much in memory, instead `dd` has to keep going back and reading more. What you want is to match the time it takes for a read to return up with the time it takes to store and write. And so `dd bs=64k <i >o` is faster than `dd bs=1M <i >o`. And I wasn't fishing - but saying thanks is antithetical to the se model. `cp` buffers too.

Comment: @mikeserv: Regarding your comment on upvotes, I want to tell you a very general fact, that might be useful for you. I always wait a bit before giving up/down votes, or choosing an answer. I do this, because I need time to understand what people write and if they are right. I don't like voting before I understand :) I could imagine that other askers also don't know how to vote before spending some time on trying out answers, but I don't know.

Comment: @MadsSkjern - I believe that's true - but my comment was for Benjamin. I just considered it weird that someone would take the time to write thanks for an answer which they didn't upvote. Seems the easier thing would be to click the button.

Comment: @MadsSkjern: and even after five years you did not select one of the answers? It seems that you needed that much time to rethink this to forgot it completely...

Comment: @Marvin: Appologies, and good that you reminded me. I will read through the answers after work and choose the best one. I still believe that people should not immediately choose best answer.

Comment: @MadsSkjern LOL.. I really did not expect that you will answer that :D but it's good, i think they all deserve the acceptance of their answers :)
But better choose any answer instead of forgetting it 5 years - at least if it's correct and more than one sentence... Also your question was "does dd copy everything" -> this was already answered completely and sufficiently with the first post by Fiximan... Better answers will get their points anyway, while getting more upvotes than the accepted :D

Answer (score 8):

Just do:

```
cp /dev/block_device imgfile
```

If *`imgfile`* will be located on a file-system which understands such things, a GNU `cp` *should* default to writing the image sparsely. You can specify your preference, though, like...

```
cp --sparse=always /dev/sda imgfile
```

`dd`'s primary usefulness is in its ability to reliably take only a specified *portion* of a stream, or that it can very efficiently apply certain conversions to same. If you want a 1:1 copy of *all* of a file then just `cp` it.

Comment: What does sparsely mean here?

Comment: @MadsSkjern - it means that the filesystem can encode a *hole* in a file that represents so many null-bytes in such a way that the file need not use all of the disk space allocated to the file. And so you can write a *sparse* file like: `</dev/null dd bs=64k seek=1 of=sparse; ls -slh sparse` which prints `0 -rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 64K Jul 29 01:17 sparse` where `ls` indicates that the *`sparse`* file uses 0 bytes of *space* but *represents* 64k worth of empty space. To explicitly include empty blocks w/ GNU `cp`: `cp --sparse=never sourcefile targetfile`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, sparsely does the opposite of what I asked for? Not that it's not valuable information. Also, if I make a sparse copy, can I then restore it back to a disk, so that the disk has all those holes? I'm not gonna do the sparse thing, I'm just curious.

Comment: @MadsSkjern - you *should* do the sparse thing. `cp` will be looking at the block dev - not the fs's representation of that. And so `cp` will skip *writing* the NULs and *seek* to the offset of the sequence's end-point before writing more bytes - it means there is less direct disk access in the *write* operation - not the read. And sparse files are handled by the *filesystem* - and so it only works if the fs supports it. This means writing a sparse file directly to a block-dev - like `cp sparse /dev/something` will write 64k in NULs - because there is no fs involved there.

Comment: @MadsSkjern - that aside, what you do is your own decision of course. If you would rather not write your image sparsely, then `cp --sparse=never sourcefile targetfile` is what you should do

Answer (score 4):

`dd` doesn't care what the data it copies means. Partition tables, partition contents, file fragments, empty filesystem space, it's all bytes. `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb` makes `/dev/sdb` an exact copy of `/dev/sda`, provided that `sdb` is at least as large as `sda` (plus some trailing junk that won't be directly accessible if `sdb` is larger).

All the magic is in the `sdX` block devices. `dd` is just a tool to copy bytes around.

This doesn't mean that `dd` is the best tool for the job though. It's somewhat error-prone and typically not the fastest thing around. I found [`cat` to be faster when copying between different disks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd). [`dd` can lose data in somewhat unintuitive ways](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial) (though I *think* that a modern Linux system is safe in this respect). Using `cat` has the additional advantage that there's less of a risk of destroying your data to a typo (like swapping `if` and `of`): the output is specified via the familiar shell redirection operator (you can use this syntax for `dd` too, by the way).

```
cat /dev/sda >/dev/sdb
```

If your other disk is larger, you can make an image of the disk in a file:

```
cat /dev/sda >/path/to/disk.img
```

Such a disk image can't be used directly: you can't boot off it. But copying it back to a disk will yield a byte-for-byte copy of the original, since the whole contents were copied both times. You can also do a [loopback mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device) to access files off it. You can make a loop device with partitions, but [Ubuntu has only had the tools for that in recent versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69363/mount-single-partition-from-image-of-entire-disk-device). If you just want to preserve your data, it's enough to copy partitions individually, and store them in individual files.

Comment: `cat`being faster than `dd` seems strange. Do you have explanation for this and in what circumstances?

Comment: @JodkaLemon I don't know, I didn't study the traces in detail. I'd have expected the chunk size (i.e. the size that's copied at a time) to be the main factor, but `dd` was slower for cross-disk copies even when tuning its chunk size.