# Is it better to use cat, dd, pv or another procedure to copy a CD/DVD?

Tags: linux, dd, cat, disk-image, pv

### Background

I'm copying some data CDs/DVDs to ISO files to use them later without the need of them in the drive.

I'm looking on the Net for procedures and I found a lot:

- Use of `cat` to copy a medium: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialCDBurn.html

  ```
  cat /dev/sr0 > image.iso
  ```
- Use of `dd` to do so (apparently the most widely used): http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/archiving-cds-iso-commandline

  ```
  dd if=/dev/cdrom bs=blocksize count=count of=/path/to/isoimage.iso
  ```
- Use of just `pv` to accomplish this: See `man pv` for more information, although here's an excerpt of it:

  ```
  Taking an image of a disk, skipping errors:
        pv -EE /dev/sda > disk-image.img

  Writing an image back to a disk:
        pv disk-image.img > /dev/sda

  Zeroing a disk:
        pv < /dev/zero > /dev/sda
  ```

I don't know if all of them should be equivalent, although I tested some of them (using the `md5sum` tool) and, at least, `dd` and `pv` are *not* equivalent. Here's the `md5sum` of both the drive and generated files using each procedure:

md5 of dd procedure: `71b676875b0194495060b38f35237c3c`

md5 of pv procedure: `f3524d81fdeeef962b01e1d86e6acc04`

**EDIT:** That output was from another CD than the output given. In fact, I realized there are some interesting facts I provide as an answer.

In fact, the size of each file *is different* comparing to each other.

So, is there a best procedure to copy a CD/DVD or am I just using the commands incorrectly?

---

### More information about the situation

Here is more information about the test case I'm using to check the procedures I've found so far:

`isoinfo -d i /dev/sr0`
Output: https://gist.github.com/JBFWP286/7f50f069dc5d1593ba62#file-isoinfo-output-19-aug-2015

`dd` to copy the media, with output checksums and file information
Output: https://gist.github.com/JBFWP286/75decda0a67605590d32#file-dd-output-with-md5-and-sha256-19-aug-2015

`pv` to copy the media, with output checksums and file information
Output: https://gist.github.com/JBFWP286/700a13fe0a2f06ce5e7a#file-pv-output-with-md5-and-sha256-19-aug-2015

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: are the file sizes identical? result of `cmp file1 file2`? did you use `dd` with the wrong `count=` (or really any count at all which is not necessary if you want the whole thing?). Read errors in dmesg?

Comment: It goes without saying that files of different sizes are (with 99.9999999999+% probability) are going to have different checksums.  As long as you've done the tests, it would be nice if you would post all the results, to include (1) the exact `dd` command that you used (what blocksize? what count?), (2) the sizes and checksums of all outputs, and (3) any independent information you have regarding the amount of data on the source optical disc.  … … … … … …  P.S. Why are you using `count=` on `dd`?  You want to copy the entire disk image, don't you?  `count=` says "copy this many and then stop".

Comment: @Scott In this page http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/archiving-cds-iso-commandline the author says one should use `isoinfo -d -i /dev/cdrom` to know the count number and use it -- in fact, he says one shouldn't use just `dd`. "In any case, if you want a proper ISO image of that CD you need to get the blocksize and blockcount correct before you create your image."

Comment: @frostschutz In the first case the sizes weren't identical, but surprisingly, I tried again and got different results. See the answer I provided for more details.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

All of the following commands are equivalent. They read the bytes of the CD `/dev/sr0` and write them to a file called `image.iso`.

```
cat /dev/sr0 >image.iso
cat </dev/sr0 >image.iso
tee </dev/sr0 >image.iso
dd </dev/sr0 >image.iso
dd if=/dev/cdrom of=image.iso
pv </dev/sr0 >image.iso
cp /dev/sr0 image.iso
tail -c +1 /dev/sr0 >image.iso
```

Why would you use one over the other?

- Simplicity. For example, if you already know `cat` or `cp`, you don't need to learn yet another command.
- Robustness. This one is a bit of a variant of simplicity. How much risk is there that changing the command is going to change what it does? Let's see a few examples:

  - Anything with redirection: you might accidentally put a redirection the wrong way round, or forget it. Since the destination is supposed to be a non-existing file, `set -o noclobber` should ensure that you don't overwrite anything; however you might overwrite a device if you accidentally write `>/dev/sda` (for a CD, which is read-only, there's no risk, of course). This speaks in favor of `cat /dev/sr0 >image.iso` (hard to get wrong in a damaging way) over alternatives such as `tee </dev/sr0 >image.iso` (if you invert the redirections or forget the input one, `tee` will write to `/dev/sr0`).
  - `cat`: you might accidentally concatenate two files. That leaves the data easily salvageable.
  - `dd`: `i` and `o` are close on the keyboard, and somewhat unusual. There's no equivalent of `noclobber`, `of=` will happily overwrite anything. The redirection syntax is less error-prone.
  - `cp`: if you accidentally swap the source and the target, the device will be overwritten (again, assuming a non read-only device). If `cp` is invoked with some options such as `-R` or `-a` which some people add via an alias, it will copy the device node rather than the device content.
- Additional functionality. The one tool here that has useful additional functionality is `pv`, with its powerful reporting options.
  But here you can check how much has been copied by looking at the size of the output file anyway.
- Performance. This is an I/O-bound process; the main influence in performance is the buffer size: the tool reads a chunk from the source, writes the chunk to the destination, repeats. If the chunk is too small, the computer spends its time switching between tasks. If the chunk is too large, the read and write operations can't be parallelized. The optimal chunk size on a PC is typically around a few megabytes but this is obviously very dependent on the OS, on the hardware, and on what else the computer is doing. I made [benchmarks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492) for hard disk to hard disk copies a while ago, on Linux, which showed that for copies within the same disk, `dd` *with a large buffer size* has the advantage, but for cross-disk copies, `cat` won over any `dd` buffer size.

There are a few reasons why you find `dd` mentioned so often. Apart from performance, they aren't particularly good reasons.

- In very old Unix systems, some text processing tools couldn't cope with binary data (they used [null-terminated strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) internally, so they tended to have problems with null bytes; some tools also assumed that characters used only 7 bits and didn't process 8-bit character sets properly). I'm not sure if this ever was a problem with `cat` (it was with more line-oriented tools such as `head`, `sed`, etc.), but people tended to avoid it on binary data because of its association with text processing. This is not a problem on modern systems such as Linux, OSX, *BSD, or anything that's POSIX-compliant.
- There's a sort of myth that `dd` is somewhat “lower level” than other tools such as `cat` and accesses devices directly. This is completely false: `dd` and `cat` and `tee` and the others all read bytes from their input and write the bytes to their output. The real magic is in `/dev/sr0`.
- `dd` has an unusual command line syntax, so explaining how it works gives more of an opportunity to shine by explaining something that just writing `cat /dev/sr0`.
- Using `dd` **with a large buffer size** can have better performance, but it is not always the case (see [some benchmarks on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492)).

A major risk with `dd` is that [**it can silently skip some data**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial). I think `dd` is safe as long as `skip` or `count` are not passed but I'm not sure whether this is the case on all platforms. But it has no advantage except for performance.

So just use `pv` if you want its fancy progress report, or `cat` if you don't.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time writting this response! =) Now I understand the differences between them. Just a question: Is `pv < /dev/sr0 > image.iso` the same as `pv /dev/sr0 > image.iso` (the latter is found in the manual pages of pv)?

Comment: @JBFWP286 They copy the same thing, but `pv /dev/sr0 …` can include the file name in progress reports whereas `pv </dev/sr0` can't.

Comment: Another note: `cp` might be aliased to `cp -R`, which (at least on GNU cp, as root) causes `cp` to copy the *device node* rather than its contents.

Comment: @marcelm Thanks for your comment. Just a question: what does "copy the device node" means? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JBFWP286 A [device node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) is a file through which you access hardware or other special features provided by kernel drivers. Almost all files in `/dev` are device nodes. For example `cp -R /dev/sr0 image.iso` would make `image.iso` a file through which the CD drive is accessed, just like `/dev/sr0`, instead of a regular file containing copy of the content of the CD which you get with `cp /dev/sr0 image.iso`.

Comment: I'm confused. You conclude by saying that `dd` has better performance, but that you should use `pv` or `cat` anyway. Also, it's worth noting that as of Ubuntu 12.0, `dd` comes with `status=progress`, so there doesn't seem to be any reason to use `pv` over it.

Comment: @Hashim I don't conclude that it *has* better performance. I mention that it has better performance *sometimes*. I've linked to a benchmark I made — in the best case `dd` beat `cat` but only by a slight margin.

Comment: I would like to see some evidence for _"In very old Unix systems, text processing tools such as cat couldn't cope with binary data."_ The `cat` command (without options) has always simply copied bytes from input to output, and this philosophy that "a file is just a bag of bytes" distinguished Unix from most contemporaneous operating systems.

Comment: @RichVel You may be right, I'm not sure about `cat`. Line-oriented tools such as `head`, `sed`, etc. certainly did have trouble with null bytes, but the [original optionless `cat` written in assembly](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V2/cmd/cat.s) didn't, nor the [V7](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/cat.c) and [BSD](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.4BSD/usr/src/bin/cat/cat.c) C implementations.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the clarification and update, +1'ed

Comment: You can also check status by hitting CTRL+T -- with cp, on OS X, it gives % of copy; with dd it shows the number of bytes copied and transfer rate.

Comment: `pv -pe` works better in showing progress and remaining time, if you give the input file as an argument, instead of redirecting it to standard input like you do in your example.

Comment: `dd` can have arguments such as `oflag=dsync`, `oflag=sync`, `conv=fdatasync` and `conv=fsync`. They can be useful when writing to a removable device, right?

Comment: @jarno Not much. `cat … && sync` is typically faster (no need to sync every block) and just as useful.

Comment: Info page tells the `conv=fdatasync` "Synchronize output data just before finishing." So I suppose it does not sync a block at a time.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using generic tools like `cat` or `dd`, one should prefer tools which are more reliable on read errors like

- [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html)
- [readcd](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/readcd.1.html) (which has error corrections/retry mechanisms for CD/DVD drives built-in)

In addition, their default settings are more suitable than e.g. `dd`'s.

Answer (score 5):

There are interesting facts in this case, specially these ones:

- I've just checked the output I got and provided (I used another disc this time, exactly, the Xubuntu 15.04 x64 setup disc), and with both procedures (`dd` and `pv`) the checksums are *identical*.
- I had the idea to, after doing the `dd` procedure, open the drive and close it with the same disc, and then finish the test with the `pv` procedure. Doing just that, I got identical copies with both procedures.
- I *think* I got different checksums the first time, because for some reason, the data collected from the CD/DVD drive seems to be "recorded" to other purposes for some time (like a cache) -- thus, other operations like checksums were made a lot faster than the transfer. Please comment if you know the exact cause for this.
- Another fact is that `dd` w/o the `count=X` parameter stops correctly at the end of the disc and gives the same disc-image as with `pv` (checksums are identical), so it's better for me to use `dd` w/o parameters or just `pv`.

So, for now, it seems `pv` and `dd` can accomplish a CD/DVD copy with same results.