# How to limit speed of file copy?

Tags: files, nfs, file-copy, limit, bandwidth

I am copying huge file from NFS mount using `dd`:

```
dd if=/mnt/nfs/image.img of=/dev/sda
```

I need to limit the speed of reading from NFS. How can I achieve it? The only precondition is to use some easy compilable utility in order to put into my custom ram-only live linux distro.

Comment: [Forget about `dd`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224277/is-it-better-to-use-cat-dd-pv-or-another-procedure-to-copy-a-cd-dvd/224314#224314). It would be simpler, less error-prone and faster to run `cat /mnt/nfs/image.img >/dev/sda`

Comment: Still I need to limit the speed becauseI have around 40 similar boxes copying from NFS and image is 2GB, thus killing NFS  box and network.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`pv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv):

```
</mnt/nfs/image.img pv -L 5m >/dev/sda
```

The `-L` flag limits the    throughput to 5 megabytes per second. `pv` also writes to the stdout so you have to redirect to the target with `>`.

Comment: @Gilles Sure, thanks for the edit. =) Sometimes I think around too many corners, without seeing the obvious..