# How to decrease speed/priority of file transfer (graphical)?

Tags: limit, file-transfer

I regularly have big transfers of files running between two local hard drives, and at the same time some network transfers through my Internet browser. The problem is that the local transfer seems to take the priority:

- if I let both of them run, the Internet transfer hardly goes higher than 100-200kBps, often being close to 1-5kBps.
- if I pause the local transfer, the Internet transfer jump immediately to 500-600kBps, which is my usual bandwidth.

I have tried to decrease the priority of the local process and increase the priority of the browser (process priority as well as I/O priority), but nothing changes.

I have seen [this topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225455/how-to-limit-speed-of-file-copy) on `pv`, but it is about a command line transfer where `pv` is used to launch the transfer, so not something I can use on an existing transfer process/window:

I would like to know if there is some ways to limit the local transfers launched graphically, like through dolphin or nautilus. Exactly (limit transfer speed) or approximatively (limit priority-like stuff and let the system manage the details).

Comment: You could always try simple wrapper scripts like, e.g. `ionice ... firefox` and use them as "graphical launcher"

Comment: Well, if ionice is equivalent to launching KSysGuard (I am on KDE) and setting the I/O priority, then it does not work at all. Modifying it through the graphical interface did not change anything (although the priority was changed, no change was observed in the behaviours). Moreover, it would be a "once for all" limitation, which is not really adapted.

Comment: Useful question, but rather broad.  Seems that if the frontend for the transfer provides such functionality or not would depend entirely on the frontend and how it was coded.  I.e. KDE (Dolphin) and GNOME (Nautilus) have very different architectures with not much shared between them — excepting a bit of competitive design similarity.