# Errors on cloning disk with cat

Tags: dd, cat, disk, cloning

I wish to clone a large disk (a 500GB SSD, for what it's worth), and I am leaning toward using `cat`, as suggested by Gilles [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/224314/49626). But what gave me pause is that I do not really know what `cat` does upon read errors. I know how `dd` behaves in these cases, *i.e.* the command

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=64K conv=noerror,sync status=progress
```

does not stop for errors on read, and pads the read error with zeroes (the `sync` option) so that data stays in sync. Unfortunately, it does so by padding the zeroes **at the end** of the block to be written, so that a single error in an early 512-byte read messes up the whole 64K of data (even worse with larger, faster block sizes).

So I am wondering: can I do better/differently with `cat`? Or should I just move on to *Clonezilla*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`cat` stops if it encounters a read or write error.

If you’re concerned there might be unreadable sectors on your source drive, you should look at tools such as [`ddrescue`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/).

Comment: ddrescue is the way to go, It helped me clone multiple severely-corrupted disks.

Answer (score 1):

### If no sectors that are bad or difficult to read,

I would recommend [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org). It is safer because thare are checkpoints (questions if you want to continue)

`cat` and `dd` and `ddrescue` assume that you know exactly what to do and that you double-check before pressing the Enter key. 'They do what you tell them to do without any question, even if you tell them to wipe the family pictures.'

Furthermore, Clonezilla is smart enough to only copy used blocks (and skip free blocks), which makes the cloning much faster.

### If you expect sectors that are bad or difficult to read,

I agree with @StevenKitt that `ddrescue` is a good tool. The info pages contain a good tutorial,

```
info ddrescue
```