# dd without sudo to image a partition

Tags: sudo, dd, usb-drive

I need to create an image of a partition of a usb drive:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=sdb1.img
```

Is there a way to do it without sudo/su? Maybe by changing permissions on the usb drive? What would be the security implications?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you are trying to allow users on a multiuser system to image a specific disk, one solution could be to run `dd if=/dev/sdb1` as a root user (or present it in some secure way with a suid binary), with a normal user redirecting the output into a file of their choice.

Comment: This doesn't solve the permission issue, but [note that you don't need](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224277/is-it-better-to-use-cat-dd-pv-or-another-procedure-to-copy-a-cd-dvd) `dd` for this, you could just do `sudo cat /dev/sdb1 > sdb1.img`.

Comment: I ma trying to image a small partition on a specific usb drive to back it up online. Having to sudo is annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to do it without sudo/su? Maybe by changing permissions on the usb drive?

If your `/dev/sdb1` has permissions like:

```
$ ls -l /dev/sdb1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 17 Apr 25 17:07 /dev/sdb1
```

Then an option would be to add your user to the `disk` group:

```
# usermod --append --groups disk username
```

After that, the next time that the user logs in, they'll be able to read the device.  Your `dd` should work after that.

> What would be the security implications?

Since the user can read *any* disk directly, the user would have access to files owned by any user on *any* disk.

The user would be able to not only read **any** disk, but would also be able to *write* directly to **any** block device file with the same permissions `(g+rw)`.  That user could easily corrupt any filesystem by accidentally writing to those block device files.  Changing permissions to disallow the `disk` group write permissions might have other side effects that I can't predict.

As a result, if you're on a multi-user system or on a system where you care about data stored on **any** disk, I don't recommend you do this.  Normal users aren't given access to block devices *because* of the security implications.

Comment: Note that this likely gives read/write access to **all disks**, not just the USB drive. Seems like kind of an important detail, especially considering that the OP is asking about security implications ;)

Comment: @marcelm good call.  I've updated my answer to clarify that this approach applies to any disk.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a USB drive and presumably portable, the obvious workaround I ended up using before was to create the image on a machine where you do have sudo access, and then move the image file to the target system afterwards (possibly on a larger USB drive)