# Extract the contents of an ISO image to a folder in one step

Tags: iso

Is there a way to extract the contents of an ISO image file to a folder in one step?

I have been doing this and want to do less typing, and not to have to do the `mount -o loop` as well as the need to be root to do the mount command to access the ISO image contents:

```bsh
cp rhel-server-7.6-x86_64-dvd.iso /home/ron/
mkdir /home/ron/temp
mount -o loop /root/rhel-server-7.6-x86_64-dvd.iso /home/ron/temp
mkdir /home/ron/rhel7.6dvd
mv /home/ron/temp/* /home/ron/rhel7.6dvd
rmdir /home/ron/temp
```

Comment: Why not put your commands into a script and run that?

Comment: it would still require root to do the mount command, which i don't feel I should need to just access the contents of an iso file.  I really like the `7z x my.iso` not sure it can get any better than that.

Comment: Slightly related: *[Can I download and write a disk image to partition without saving as a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685233/)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's multiple programs that can just treat an ISO-9660 file as an archive. `7z` is a popular one: `7z x yourfile.iso` works.

If this is a modern Linux with a user session manager running, `udisksctl loop-setup -f yourfile.iso` is a way to get your file into a loop device, and consequently automounted.

Also:

```bsh
mv /home/ron/temp/* /home/ron/rhel7.6dvd
```

that line must be throwing a lot of errors: a mounted ISO image is read-only, so you can't move things away from it. `cp` instead.

Comment: **note:** for anyone doing the `7z x my.iso` it explodes the contents into the current folder, which can be problematic.  So make an empty subfolder first and then execute `7z` from within that empty subfolder.  No different than doing a `tar -xf` for example.

Answer (score 5):

`osirrox -indev rhel-server-7.6-x86_64-dvd.iso -extract / /home/ron/rhel7.6dvd`

`osirrox` is a special invocation of the `xorriso` tool.

https://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso/

Comment: this works.  but gonna mark the `7z x my.iso` one as correct since it was the least amount of typing.   I was able to `yum install xorriso` on RHEL 7.9 with having the EPEL repository available.  Thanks for the suggestion, always nice to find a new linux tool.

Comment: seconding that, even have xorriso installed, but for the love of it couldn't remember how to find it ^^". Have a very well-deserved upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Users running FreeBSD can:

```
mkdir /home/ron/rhel7.6dvd
tar xpf rhel-server-7.6-x86_64-dvd.iso -C /home/ron/rhel7.6dvd
```

Other BSDs might support this as well, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks -- also available as `bsdtar` in Ubuntu and other Debian based distros after installing the `libarchive-tools` package.

Comment: This would also work on MidnightBSD