# How to unzip and dd a disk image to an SD Card with a single command?

Tags: dd, zip

I am under the following restrictions:

- I have a 1.0 GB `.zip` file on my computer which contains one file, a disk image of `raspbian`. When uncompressed, this file is 3.2 GB large and named `2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie.img`.
- After having downloaded the zip file, I have just under 1.0 GB of storage space on my computer, not enough space to extract the image to my computer.
- This file needs to be uncompressed and written to an SD card using plain old `dd`.

Is it possible for me to write the image to the SD card under these restrictions?

I know it's possible to pipe data through `tar` and then pipe that data elsewhere, however, will this still work for the `zip` file format, or does the entire archive need to be uncompressed before any files are accessible?

Comment: I realize I could just extract the zip file to an external flash drive, but this is more fun. I want to pull this off for the challenge (and learning experience) of it!

Comment: If your SD card is device `/dev/sdh`, then run `unzip -p file.zip >/dev/sdh`.  (I know that the use of `dd` is traditional but it is not necessary.)

Comment: Huh.  Would that work without `dd`?  I figured the Block Size parameter would be needed.

Comment: Yes, it works without `dd`.  In the past, block size was very important when writing to tapes.  For disks, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @TheCzar Aside from tapes, the block size parameter to `dd` can only [lose data](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial) or [slow things down](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492) (or in rare case speed things up a little, if large enough). Forget about `dd`, it's very rarely useful.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `unzip -p`:

```bsh
unzip -p 2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie.zip 2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie.img | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
```

`-p` extracts files to stdout

Comment: The code is running, and neither my harddrive space nor my RAM is running out. All good so far.

Comment: Or simply `unzip -p … >/dev/sdb`.

Comment: @Gilles besides the downside, `dd` is sometimes useful with `sudo`: `unzip -p ... | sudo dd of=/dev/sdb bs=1M`

Comment: @yaegashi `unzip -p … | sudo 'cat >/dev/sdb'` But I prefer `sudo chown $USER /dev/sdb` which gives me an extra opportunity to check that I'm writing to the right device.

Comment: It worked beautifully! Mind if I edit in the exact file name in case anyone just wants to copy and paste the command?

Comment: What if the archive is xz? I'm finding that the archive is first being extracted in full before committing it to disk. If the archive is huge as it is in my case then the whole source disk gets full before the operation can complete. Should I be using another archive format instead of xz?

Comment: @Gilles: I get `sudo: cat >/dev/sdb: command not found`.  I feel like the emperor has no clothes; I believe that your ``sudo 'cat >/dev/sdb'`` command would never work, and would never have worked, but here I am, posting the first comment on it, after almost six years.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' No, that should have been `sudo -s 'cat >/dev/sdb'`

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of struggling with the former solution:

```
 unzip -p ~/Downloads/2020-02-05-raspbian-buster-lite.zip | sudo dd of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m
```

or, if you want to see the progress and you have installed `pv`:

```
 unzip -p ~/Downloads/2020-02-05-raspbian-buster-lite.zip | pv | sudo dd of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m
```

Comment: note that some versions of dd will require a capital M instead of a lowercase for the bs= option.

Comment: or use the `dd` with the `status=progress` option of your version of `dd` supports it

Comment: note that this answer presumes the zip file only contains the image file. Use `unzip -l` to check

Answer (score 0):

I typically use `unzip -p 2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie.zip >/dev/sdb` or `zcat 2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie.gz >/dev/sdb` for convenience. This is because when doing large data transfer, we expect the operating system to automatically adjust block size (according to source block size, target block size, memory availability, etc.) for optimal performance, and it turns out they work faster than `dd if= of= bs=` (maybe because I did not by-brute-force try out all possible choices of blocksizes for `dd`) ^_^