# How to burn .zip image to SD card from command line?

Tags: cat, zip

A [dd solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226222/182280) is provided:

```
unzip -p 2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie.zip 2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie.img | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
```

however dd is contra-indicated with the availability of `cat`.  I would like to constrain the question to answers that do not use `dd`solutions.  Solutions engaging `cat` (good) or `pv`(better) to write to the SD card are preferred over `dd`.

An image of an SD card was [successfully copied](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522514/182280) to sdcard.image with the `cat` command and burned to a second SD card:

```
sudo sh -c 'pv /dev/disk2 >sdcard.image'
```

`/dev/disk2` is the SD card

The SD card image is 32GB and was zipped to an 8GB file: sdcard.image.zip.  From the command line, how does one unzip and burn the file?  Assume there is not enough space to unzip the image to the Macbook's SSD.

The goal is to avoid writing the 32GB file to the laptop's SSD and burn the compressed image directly to the SD card.

Comment: @Freddy  Very close, the idea of unzipping and piping the contents into a write command is what I had envisioned.   I should have initially constrained the question to preclude `dd` solutions  given that they are contra-indicated in favor of `cat`.

Comment: With `unzip` as the input you probably do want `dd` in the pipeline to coalesce part block reads into single block-sized writes. (`iflag=fullblock`).

Comment: @roaima: I would guess that the SD card driver would make this unnecessary.  What am I overlooking?

Comment: @G-Man I'd prefer to write entire blocks rather than dribbles. Efficiency, and reducing the number of consecutive partial writes to the same SSD disk block.

Comment: @roaima: Well, we agree that doing multiple **physical** writes to the same **physical** block of a storage device is a bad thing.  But (1) when I started using Unix, there were two kinds of device nodes (`/dev` entries→inodes) for storage devices: block special devices (a.k.a. “cooked”), e.g., `hd0`, and character special devices (a.k.a. “raw”), e.g., `rhd0`.  The raw device interface permitted more-or-less direct access to the hardware, which was sometimes beneficial (especially in the case of large block sizes) and often deleterious (especially in the case of small block sizes).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  By contrast, the cooked device driver put a buffer between userland and the hardware.  If a process wrote 42 bytes to ```/dev/hd0```, the driver would keep those bytes in a buffer in kernel memory, and write (or “flush”) them out to the hardware only when the process had written another 470 bytes (i.e., for a total of 512) or a long period of time had elapsed.  (I apologize if this comes across as pedantic.  I assume that you already know this, but I wanted to be sure that we were on the same page.)  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  In the past ten or twenty years, raw disk devices have been going away, leaving us with only the cooked version.   So my point is that I don’t see much benefit in adding a userland process to do what the kernel is already doing.   That seems *less* efficient.   Also, (2) it’s my understanding that SSD controllers (i.e., the firmware in the hardware) doesn’t *really* allow multiple writes to the same block.   That you never really overwrite a block; rather, it allocates a new block, writes that, remaps the *block **number*** to the new block, … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  and then (eventually) erases the original block.  That’s still no excuse for making the hardware do more work than it needs to; I’m just suggesting that it’s less harmful than you make it sound.   (And, *again,* I assume that you know about wear leveling, but that it merely slipped your mind.)

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I also remember raw and cooked disk devices. And hard drives that had a head-park switch as well as a power switch... :-/ Maybe I'm being overcautious, but I have had recent (last year or so) issues with uncompressed streams, partial blocks, and short (incomplete) writes. As a result I prefer to ensure my data is explicitly aggregated into whole blocks.

Answer (score 1):

```
unzip -p sdcard.image.zip sdcard.image >/dev/disk2/
```

[man unzip](https://ss64.com/osx/zip.html) provides an explanation of unzip with options shown for MacOS X, and [this link](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/unzip/unzip.1.en.html) is the equivalent for Debian.

FYI, data is 'written' to SD cards because they are an inherently read-write medium; 'burning' is a term used for optical media.  If you are copying data out of an archive (zip or otherwise), you are 'extracting' it.

Comment: The OP has been updated to indicate the SD card is at `/dev/disk2/`.  If /dev/sdb is replaced with /dev/disk2/ should I expect the command to write the .image file to the SD card as it is unzipped?   Does the `...` act as a wildcard or do I need to replace this with the image filename?  Thank you

Comment: ... just means "gimme the fully qualified path name" a la https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name#Path_names

Comment: The suggested command has been updated with a concrete example: my best guess at what I think you are suggesting.   Please adjust as necessessary.

Comment: How about  unzip -p sdcard.image.zip > /dev/disk2/sdcard.image