# Pretty print output of "kill -USR1"-ing dd

Tags: dd, output, watch

When `dd` is done it prints a three line summary about the number of read and written segments, the total size and average writing speed. While it does its work, `dd` is awfully quiet.

Not too long ago (mea culpa) I discovered that I can make `dd` print the three line summary **while it is still doing work** by emitting `SIGUSR1`. Ever since I do

```
dd <magic incantation> &
watch kill -USR1 $!
```

The problem is, that with this the three lines of `dd`'s summary are not left aligned. Each following line starts at the column the previous line ended. So I'm guessing `dd` prints a newline character, but not a carriage return and whatever `watch` uses to print output expects carriage returns.

I tried putting `| sed -e '<expression>'` behind the kill command different sorts of quoting but the output I get presented does not change at all.

How can I pretty print the `dd` output in this scenario?

Comment: Get `gnu dd v. 8.24`, [it displays progress/summary](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227101).

Comment: Consider `pv -d`. In cases you don't need features specific to `dd`, maybe you can use `pv` instead of `dd` in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `kill -USR1` to know where `dd` is at. You can use [`lsof`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) to display the position of its input file descriptor. Getting parseable output is a bit abstruse, but it works. Note that the `0` is the input file descriptor; if you pass a `if=…` argument to `dd` rather letting it read from standard input, then depending on your implementation of `dd`, it might read from a different descriptor.

```
lsof -a -o -p $! -d 0 -F o | sed -n 's/^o[0-9]*t//p'
```

On Linux, you can get this information directly from `/proc`.

```
</proc/$!/fdinfo/0 awk '$1 == "pos:" {print $2}'
```

You might as well use `cat` instead of `dd`: [it's often faster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd) and [it's less error-prone](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04 terminal. But launching from RXVT make the display behave correctly :

```
sudo su - # From the default Ubuntu terminal
dd if=... &
rxvt
watch -n 0.5 kill -USR1 <process number of the dd>
```

(but well, I don't know why.)