# Which command produces more data per second?

Tags: performance, data, pv

Which command produces more data per second? This could be useful to quickly fill a file with garbage data or to test data transfer rates. So far, I found that "/dev/zero" is the quickest one.

```
$ cat /dev/urandom | pv > /dev/null
3,04GO 0:08:22 [5,83MB/s] [ <=>                                  ]

$ yes | pv > /dev/null
38GO 0:11:56 [40,2MB/s] [          <=>                        ]

$ cat /dev/zero | pv > /dev/null
754GO 0:08:52 [ 1,4GB/s] [                      <=>             ]
```

Would you suggest another possible faster command?

Comment: For me `dd if=/dev/zero bs=8192 | pv > /dev/null` is giving the best results.

Comment: Just beware that testing data transfer rates with a stream of zeros to a filesystem that compresses data - such as BTRFS or ZFS (among others) - will product wildly inaccurate results as a stream of identical values compresses *really* well.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro In my case I got 2.84GB/s with your command versus 3.2 GB/s with cat. But by tunning "bs" I got almost the same (40k for me).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Good point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system interprets `/dev/zero` as literally just an endless stream of zeroes, and I believe this is the fastest way to obtain useless information. In all likelihood, you're going to be bottlenecked by your physical disk speed, and so this *should* be as fast as you'd ever need even if there are any faster methods.

Also, when testing, I was surprised to find that `cat` was much faster than `dd` for this!

Comment: I did not thought about dd, but looking for it, cat could [sometimes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492) be faster than dd. I guess it is dependent on the implementation.

Comment: At least on my system, which is Xubuntu and EXT4, `cat` is faster than `dd`. Like you, I also got ~10% slower with Rui F Ribeiro's `dd` command.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
pv /dev/zero >/dev/null
```

Comment: This one is much faster (by a factor of 10), but still I was looking for a command producing data for a file. If you redirect this command to a file, it won't be as fast as you can see executing: `pv /dev/zero | pv`. Anyway thank you for this idea and welcome to stackexchange!