# optimum value for bs in 'dd' for chrooted linux?

Tags: performance, dd

I am trying to install chrooted debian (arm64) on my android phone(snapdragon650 & 3GB RAM). I found many tutorials for it.
Almost all the guides mentioned this cmd for creating img for chrooted debian.

```
 dd if=/dev/zero of=jessie-arm64.img bs=1M count=0 seek=5120
```

Here  bs=1M . I don't know much about dd. But I think bs parameter is gonna affect ::

1. read/write speed on img
2. Space allocation to files & their file size

I am going to use chrooted environment for compiling source code for arm64 and running a bit heavy gui programs (in openbox or xfce ).
I want that value for bs which would be optimum for both read/write speed and space utilisation.

Comment: This dd command zeros the image.  It seems likely that you will only be doing this once.  Speed should not matter.

Comment: What about  the file size  like a file having actual file size 300KB but taking space 1MB on img ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to determine the optimal value for the bs parameter to dd?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd)

Comment: @Gilles not a duplicate in this case, as the bs is only used by the human and not the hardware in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The `count=0` parameter is **very** significant here, this command is just being used to create a file of a particular size, nothing is actually being copied.

Therefore there is **no** `optimal value for bs` from the hardware point of view

The created file will have size `bs * seek`. The bs of 1 megabyte just makes it easy to see that you are creating a file with size 5120 megabytes.

At a system call level, this is just going to do an `open`, an `lseek` and a `close` call. dd will do the `bs * seek` calculation and give it to the `lseek` system call. So `bs if=/dev/zero seek=5368709120 bs=1 of=jesse-arm64.img` will produce **exactly** the same system calls.

Answer (score 2):

First, some details about the command

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=jessie-arm64.img bs=1M count=0 seek=5120
```

From the [man page of dd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) :

> - if=FILE
>              read from FILE instead of stdin
> - of=FILE
>               write to FILE instead of stdout
> - bs=BYTES
>               read and write up to BYTES bytes at a time
> - count=N
>               copy only N input blocks
> - seek=N skip N obs-sized blocks at start of output

We have `count=0`, so 0 input block will be copied but we have `seek=5120` so 5120 blocks of size `obs` will be skipped. `obs`is the output block size, in our case it's not specified so `obs=bs=1M`.

If you want you can even remove the `if=/dev/zero` and obtain the same result.

```
dd of=jessie-arm64.img bs=1M count=0 seek=5120
```

Now the question of optimum value for `bs`, we observe in the [source code of dd](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/dd.c#L2088) that even if `count=0` blocks are copied, we have `seek=5120` (`seek_records`in the source code) and the `bs` (`obs`, `output_blocksize`int the source code) value is used.

```
  if (seek_records != 0 || seek_bytes != 0)
    {
      size_t bytes = seek_bytes;
      uintmax_t write_records = skip (STDOUT_FILENO, output_file,
                                      seek_records, output_blocksize, &bytes);
      if (write_records != 0 || bytes != 0)
        {
          memset (obuf, 0, write_records ? output_blocksize : bytes);
          do
            {
              size_t size = write_records ? output_blocksize : bytes;
              if (iwrite (STDOUT_FILENO, obuf, size) != size)
                {
                  error (0, errno, _("writing to %s"), quoteaf (output_file));
                  quit (EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
              if (write_records != 0)
                write_records--;
              else
                bytes = 0;
            }
          while (write_records || bytes);
        }
}
```

The optimum value of `bs`is dependant of your hardware, here is an [article](http://blog.tdg5.com/tuning-dd-block-size/) explaining how to measure it. I will not go in detailed explanations here, because this answer is becoming too long.

Remarks:

1) You can observe your image in hexadecimal format with :

```
cat jessie-arm64.img | xxd
```

2) This is valid for the dd command from the [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html). If you are using a BSD-style `dd` command such as in macOS, you have to use `bs=1m` instead of `bs=1M`.