# Backup data of a live USB

Tags: kali-linux, backup, live-usb

I have a USB (8.0 GB, kingston) and inside it a Kali Linux image. I often used it in live mode w/ persistence, and I have some data there (plus config of the whole system) that I obviously don't want to lose.
But, by some reasons, I have to dispose myself of that USB. My question is: Is there some way to back up everything, in a way that after getting another USB I could use the backup and reinstall it?

Many people suggesting dd command, I do not know if that works because of the way that persistence bootable USB are made: [here](http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an image *from a drive*

```
sudo dd iflag=fullblock if=/dev/sdx of=/path/to/new.iso status=progress
```

Alternatively, to create a USB drive *from an image*

```
sudo dd iflag=fullblock if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sdx status=progress
```

Replace `/dev/sdx` with your USB drive, e.g. `/dev/sdc`.

**WARNING:** It is very important that you make certain you are using the correct drive. If you don't use the correct drive, you could lose your data. To check your currently mounted drives, use the command `lsblk`.

*Note:* Copying large files (1 GB or higher) can take a long time, be patient.

Comment: On Linux systems don't bother using `dd` for this kind of copy operation; use `cat` instead. It's easier and often faster (never slower). In your case the `dd` is desperately inefficient - and slow - because you're using the default (512b) block size.

Comment: @roaima I have always used `dd` for such operations, in fact, I always assumed that `cat` would be slower, but thank you for explaining it to me :)

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9492/100397 for some facts backing up my claim.

Comment: I did not knew I could use dd command for that, i had used dd before for creating the bootable USB. But now it seems there is a controversy here, I should use cat instead of dd? And if yes please edit the answer for others who might stumble here with the same question

Comment: The confusion here lies in that roaima does not acknowledge that adding iflag=fullblock will have the same effect as using cat without losing the fine-grained control.

Comment: @Tanami I have updated the post to reflect your suggestion, however I have no time to test the script, can you please verify it?

Comment: Your edit is correct, you can also use the argument status=progress to see a transfer statistics bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dd to create a disk image of your Kali USB as it were.

And then you can write that disk image to another USB of equal or greater size to restore it.

The command must not be run from within the disk to be copied (so not inside Kali).

---

The command format is `dd if=/dev/sdX of=/dst status=progress`

Where *sdX* is the /dev device for the USB drive which has the Kali install on it.

And *dst* is where you want to put the image, i.e. (/home/user/kali.img)

---

dd is a very powerful command so you must double-check the if=/ and of=/ flags or else you may corrupt your main hard drive.

Comment: On Linux systems don't bother using `dd` for this kind of copy operation; use `cat` instead. It's easier and often faster (never slower). In your case the `dd` is desperately inefficient - and slow - because you're using the default (512b) block size. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9492/100397 for some facts backing up my claim.

Comment: This is interesting but you should see http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/page_sizes.html