# How to speed up dd on macOS High Sierra?

Tags: ubuntu, dd, macintosh

I was trying to create bootable USB of Ubuntu 17.04. First, I erased everything from the pen drive and then started to copy using `sudo dd if=path_to_ubuntu_image of=/dev/rdisk2` but it is taking around 5 hrs to complete the process. I read previous answers about speeding up it using `rdisk` instead of `disk` but I was initially using that only. There was to use `bs` but I have doubt will it bring some change in the bootable image while copying ? Please help.
Size of Ubuntu - 1.63GB
I am using the latest version of macOS High Sierra.

Link of webpage whom steps I was following - http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs171/materials/pdfs/How_to_Dual-Boot_OSX_and_Ubuntu.pdf

Comment: Use a multiple of the page size of the system as the block size.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to determine the optimal value for the bs parameter to dd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd)

Comment: According to my experience, `bs=4096` is a good option. See this link, [My standard dd block size is bs=4096](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931581/flashing-ubuntu-iso-to-usb-stick-with-dd/931588#931588)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default block size is only 512 bytes, which significantly cripples the transfer rate. You should use a block size that is a much, much larger.

[OSX Daily has step by step instructions](http://osxdaily.com/2015/06/05/copy-iso-to-usb-drive-mac-os-x-command/), they suggest 1 MB, but you might want to try even larger.

```
sudo dd if=/path/image.iso of=/dev/r(IDENTIFIER) bs=1m
```