# Compute checksum of a partition inside an image file

Tags: linux, hashsum

An external USB flash drive containing 2 partitions is connected to my Raspberry Pi.
I want to `dd` an image file to this external flash drive if the first partition on the flash drive is not the same as the first one of the image file.

To achieve that, I will compare their checksum.

It's easy to compute the checksum of the flash drive's partition :
`md5sum /dev/sda1`

However, how to compute the checksum of the first partition stored in the image file ?

I use Debian 10 operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `losetup --partscan --find --show /path/to/disk.img` to set up one or more loop devices (`/dev/loopN`) for the image and its partitions

   Example

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=100 >/tmp/100M.img

   pimg() { parted /tmp/100M.img --align optimal unit MiB "$@"; }
   pimg mklabel gpt
   pimg mkpart primary 2 50
   pimg mkpart primary 51 100%

   pimg print
     Model:  (file)
     Disk /tmp/100M.img: 100MiB
     Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
     Partition Table: gpt
     Disk Flags:

     Number  Start    End      Size     File system  Name     Flags
      1      2.00MiB  50.0MiB  48.0MiB               primary
      2      51.0MiB  100MiB   49.0MiB               primary

   lo=$(losetup --partscan --find --show /tmp/100M.img); echo $lo
     /dev/loop0

   ls ${lo}*
     /dev/loop0  /dev/loop0p1  /dev/loop0p2
   ```
2. Rather than generate two checksums, which requires both your existing target and the source image to be read in their entirety, use `cmp`. This may be more efficient that generating a checksum as it will stop as soon as there is a byte mismatch. (If there is none it will read to the end, but that's no slower than your alternative of using `md5sum`.)

   ```
   cmp /dev/loop0p1 /path/to/existing_image
   ```

   If you prefer to continue using a tool such as `md5sum` you can use the loop device we created earlier:

   ```
   md5sum /dev/loop0p1
   ```
3. Don't use `dd` - it's [at least as quick to use `cat`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9492/100397) or `pv`, and a lot easier too (no fiddly options to remember that can corrupt data if you get them wrong):

   ```
   pv /dev/loop0p1 >/path/to/existing_image
   ```

Comment: What is the downside of dd ?  Everyone seems to use it to burn an image to disk.

Comment: "Everyone" just [copies everyone else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) without concrete evidence. I've added a link to an evidential comparison of `dd` and `cat` to my answer, @fdamien12

Comment: I just realized that the image file is in a zip file and I don't have enough disk space to extract it and then mount it as loop device.
Is there a workaround ?

Comment: @fdamien12. Not easily that I know of. Assuming there's something that will read a ZIP file and output its contents to _stdout_, you could pull off just the partition table and investigate what block offsets the required partition starts/ends. Then use `dd` (yes, this time) to extract the relevant blocks from the stream into `cmp`. Then finally use `dd` again to copy the relevant blocks to the flash disk. Very complex and I wouldn't really recommend it

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the image file as a block device, and then use the `md5sum` command you show in your question.

Note that all the commands shown below assume you are running as `root`.

### For raw disk images

If it's a raw disk image, you can juse `losetup`:

```
losetup -fP --show disk.img
```

This will allocate a loop device (like `/dev/loop0`), attach the image, and expose the partitions as device `/dev/loop0p1`, `/dev/loop0p2`, etc.

When you're done, `losetup -d <device>` to disconnect the image.

### For qcow2 images

If it's a qcow2 image, you can do something similar using `qemu-nbd`:

- Load the `nbd` kernel module:

  ```
  modprobe nbd
  ```
- Attach the image to an nbd device. In this command we attach it to `/dev/nbd0`, but in the unlikely event that is already in use you can specify any available nbd device (there will be 16 by default):

  ```
  qemu-nbd -f qcow2 -c /dev/nbd0 disk.qcow4
  ```
- Image partitions will be exposed as `/dev/nbd0p1`, `/dev/nbd0p2`, etc.

When you're done, run `qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0` to disconnect the image.